# How can I make a shortcut start in a different directory when running it as an administrator on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, uac, shortcut, cmd

I have a shortcut on my desktop which opens a command prompt with many arguments that I need.  I set the 'start in' field to d:\ and it works as expected (the prompt starts in d:).  When I choose Advanced -> run as administrator and then open the shortcut, it starts in C:\Windows\System32, even though I have not changed the 'start in' field.  How can I get it to start in d:\?

Comment: This is actually a general problem with shortcuts that applies to more than just `cmd`, or indeed `cmd` scripts.  Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/672693/340790 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use the /k argument, you can add a single line to execute a change drive and change directory. For instance:

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "d: & cd d:\storage"`

Using `&` you can string together many commands on one line.

Edit: You can also change drive with the cd command alone `"cd /d d:\storage"`. Thanks to Adam Mitz for the comment.

Comment: I did not know the change directory command did that. Good to know.

Comment: As for "why" it does this, according to a Microsoft support engineer , [executing from system32 when running as admin is by design](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/command-prompt-ignores-start-in-location-when/b6c1c59c-b9a9-48bf-be9c-867e5b796f42): `"This issue is by deign as a result of which the commandline activities will run as admin from the default location as it will not start using the Start-in location or from the quick launch toolbar."`