# Running a command as Administrator using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, administrator

You know how if you're the administrative user of a system and you can just right click say, a batch script and run it as Administrator without entering the administrator password?

I'm wondering how to do this with a PowerShell script. I do not want to have to enter my password; I just want to mimic the right-click *Run As Administrator* method.

Everything I read so far requires you to supply the administrator password.

Comment: Try [`gsudo`](http://github.com/gerardog/gsudo). A free open-source sudo for windows that allows to execute as admin from the command line. A UAC pop-up will appear.

Comment: 2024: the new [`sudo` for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77965260/6309) should help.

Answer (score 462, accepted):

If the current console is not elevated and the operation you're trying to do requires elevated privileges then you can start `powershell` with the **Run as Administrator** option :

```
PS> Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```

[Microsoft Docs: Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process)

Comment: From within a `CMD` window, the shortest version of this is: `powershell start cmd -v runas`. To verify the newly acquired privileges, run: `net sess`.

Comment: Remark: The short version should only be used by typing. Inside a script you should use the full length for readability reasons.

Comment: `Start-Process wt -Verb runAs` for starting windows terminal as admin

Comment: The question is how to run a command, not to start elevated PowerShell console.

Comment: @ﾤﾡ No, it _is_ how to start an elevated PowerShell console. See this line in OP's question: "*I just want to mimic the right-click Run As Administrator method*"

Comment: @TylerH "Run as Administrator" doesn't assume a separate console and doesn't need it. All it needs is an elevation token. Letting alone your unneeded interpretation when the question clearly says "run a command". One doesn't need a console to run a command at all.

Comment: @ﾤﾡ The body of the post clearly states, multiple times, that this question is about right-clicking a file and 'running as administrator'. It's great to achieve the same outcome via a different avenue if you know how, but please don't mislead others by suggesting the question is not asking what it is asking.

Comment: @TylerH No, it isn't. "Right-clicking" is only used as an illustration that creates the same outcome. Illustrations like these are used to educate children. Now please don't bug me with your useless commentary and better learn the meaning of the relevant words: "run", "console", "elevation token", "command processor".

Comment: @ﾤﾡ OK, feel free to continue ignoring the contents of questions, and the rest of us will just continue ignoring you.

Comment: @TylerH Excuse me, the rest of who? Are you speaking on behalf of a group of users? What is your mandate? Or is it just your fantasy about representing someone? Not that I care about however large group of people ignoring me in case they are incapable of telling the syntax and the semantics apart.

Comment: `Start-Process wt -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "cmd needs super user role"` is closer to sudo ....

Answer (score 167):

Here is an addition to Shay Levi's suggestion (just add these lines at the beginning of a script):

```bsh
if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))  
{  
  $arguments = "& '" +$myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
  Break
}
```

This results in the current script being passed to a new powershell process in Administrator mode (if current User has access to Administrator mode and the script is not launched as Administrator).

Comment: Easily modified to just throw an error when not run as admin. Just take the `if` statement and put a `throw` inside the then block.

Comment: The only syntax that worked for me is in the original post, not the one by G.Lombard nor anjdreas

Comment: Is there a way of supressing windows If you want to run powershell as administrator? For applications in which you need to run this silently having your user asked can be bothering.

Comment: This answer doesn't preserve the working-directory. See here for one which does: stackoverflow.com/a/57035712/2441655

Comment: This fails when it is inside of a function definition.  Must be outside, otherwise it opens a new admin window and immediately closes.

Comment: Doesn't work if script launched from mapped network drive as admin doesn't have same mapped drive. To fix you'd have to run from UNC address or have code that expands network driver to UNC then relaunch from UNC

Comment: @gregg unless, of course, you manually map the network drive in an elevated console first.

Answer (score 145):

### Self elevating PowerShell script

Windows 8.1 / PowerShell 4.0 +

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

# Your script here
```

Comment: Yikes. So, here is a much better way:

if([bool]([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).Groups -notcontains "S-1-5-32-544" {
    Start Powershell -ArgumentList "& '$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path'" -Verb runas
    }

Comment: Drawback: If you enter a non-admin in the prompt, you end in an endless fork-exit loop.

Comment: but this don't pass args

Comment: To pass args, I modified it to: `if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \`"$PSCommandPath\`" \`"$args\`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }`

Comment: You can add `Write-Host "\`n\`nPress any key to exit scrpt ..."; $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") > $null;` at the end of your script so that the newly opened admin shell doesn't close automatically.

Comment: This answer doesn't preserve the working-directory. See here for one which does: stackoverflow.com/a/57035712/2441655

Comment: This answer probably only works on English-language systems.

Comment: @Jayowend can confirm if still works on Powershell 5.1?

Comment: For me this worked just fine. I just changed `powershell.exe` to `pwsh.exe` and using it with PS1 script that I just right click and select `Run with PowerShell 7`.

Comment: How do you preserve the arguments you pass in though? I tried @ab. 's fix but it seems adding `$args` doesn't work. It just closes the newly opened PS session and then exits the script.

Comment: @Daniel this works for me, also restarts in 64 bit if it was started in a 32 bit process on a 64 bit OS

`$CommandLine = "-NoProfile -File '$( $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path )' $( $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments )"`
`Start-Process -FilePath "$( $pshome -replace "syswow64", "System32" )\powershell.exe" -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine`

Comment: Note that it won't work if run from a drive other than C:

Comment: Also, the current working directory is different after elevation. Return to it after w/ this: `$path = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path; cd $path`

Answer (score 59):

Benjamin Armstrong posted an [excellent article about self-elevating PowerShell scripts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script/). There a few minor issue with his code; a modified version based on fixes suggested in the comment is below.

Basically it gets the identity associated with the current process, checks whether it is an administrator, and if it isn't, creates a new PowerShell process with administrator privileges and terminates the old process.

```cs
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
$myWindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID);

# Get the security principal for the administrator role
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator;

# Check to see if we are currently running as an administrator
if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
    # We are running as an administrator, so change the title and background colour to indicate this
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)";
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue";
    Clear-Host;
}
else {
    # We are not running as an administrator, so relaunch as administrator

    # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
    $newProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

    # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter with added scope and support for scripts with spaces in it's path
    $newProcess.Arguments = "& '" + $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "'"

    # Indicate that the process should be elevated
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

    # Start the new process
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

    # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
    Exit;
}

# Run your code that needs to be elevated here...

Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue...";
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
```

Comment: I was not getting the script name and params properly resolved, so I wrapped the execution in cmd.exe /c 
`$newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo “cmd.exe”
$newProcess.Arguments = ‘/c ‘ + [System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()
$newProcess.WorkingDirectory = [environment]::CurrentDirectory`

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing it like this instead of Start-Process? I am curious about the differences, between this method and the others posted above and on other threads. They both rely on .NET, but this method more heavily...

Comment: I found various comments associated with the direct link to Armstrong's post (initial sentence of this post) to be very helpful as well.

Comment: This answer doesn't preserve the working-directory. See here for one which does: stackoverflow.com/a/57035712/2441655

Answer (score 53):

Here's a self-elevating snippet for Powershell scripts **which preserves the working directory**:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
    Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`"";
    exit;
}

# Your script here
```

Preserving the working directory is important for scripts that perform path-relative operations. Almost all of the other answers do not preserve this path, which can cause unexpected errors in the rest of the script.

If you'd rather not use a self-elevating script/snippet, and instead just want an easy way to launch a script as adminstrator (eg. from the Explorer context-menu), see my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033941/2441655

Answer (score 34):

You can create a batch file (*.bat) that runs your powershell script with administrative privileges when double-clicked. In this way, you **do not need to change anything in your powershell script**.To do this, create a batch file with the same name and location of your powershell script and then put the following content in it:

```
@echo off

set scriptFileName=%~n0
set scriptFolderPath=%~dp0
set powershellScriptFileName=%scriptFileName%.ps1

powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -Command `\"cd \`\"%scriptFolderPath%`\"; & \`\".\%powershellScriptFileName%\`\"`\"\" -Verb RunAs"
```

That's it!

Here is the explanation:

Assuming your powershell script is in the path *C:\Temp\ScriptTest.ps1*, your batch file must have the path *C:\Temp\ScriptTest.bat*. When someone execute this batch file, the following steps will occur:

1. The cmd will execute the command

   ```
   powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -Command `\"cd \`\"C:\Temp\`\"; & \`\".\ScriptTest.ps1\`\"`\"\" -Verb RunAs"
   ```
2. A new powershell session will open and the following command will be executed:

   ```
   Start-Process powershell "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -Command `"cd \`"C:\Temp\`"; & \`".\ScriptTest.ps1\`"`"" -Verb RunAs
   ```
3. Another new powershell session with administrative privileges will open in the *system32* folder and the following arguments will be passed to it:

   ```
   -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -Command "cd \"C:\Temp\"; & \".\ScriptTest.ps1\""
   ```
4. The following command will be executed with administrative privileges:

   ```
   cd "C:\Temp"; & ".\ScriptTest.ps1"
   ```

   Once the script path and name arguments are double quoted, they can contain space or single quotation mark characters (').
5. The current folder will change from *system32* to *C:\Temp* and the script `ScriptTest.ps1` will be executed. Once the parameter `-NoExit` was passed, the window wont be closed, even if your powershell script throws some exception.

Comment: If I do this, I get a popup that asks me if I allow PowerShell to make changes to my system. This makes it unusable for automation.

Comment: @JohnSlegers, if you need to automate it, it's your responsibility to make sure the automated process is run as an administrator. If you could automatically elevate a non-admin process to an admin process without user interaction, that would defeat the purpose of requiring a process to have admin privileges in the first place.

Comment: @meustrus : As a [release engineer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_engineering), my job involves creating and maintaining build processes that run fully automatically, either periodically, or when certain criteria are met. Some of these processes need admin privileges, and requiring user input makes a process unusable in this context. — In Linux, you can achieve this by using the `sudo` command and [configuring the user you use for automated process with `NOPASSWD: ALL` in the `sudoers` file](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1657720&page=3&p=10317361#post10317361).

Comment: This is a better answer than the others because it preserves the working directory. I put together some one-line variants of this approach here (one for cmd/batch, one for Explorer context-menu entries, and one for powershell): https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033941/2441655

Comment: FWIW, edit #5 by @mems was wrong for me. The backslash added after `%scriptFolderPath%` caused an error for me.

Comment: Seems kind of like a kludge using a batch file to run a powershell script when the powershell script has 10x the power and flexibility of a batch file...  Just my $.02

Comment: What is the backtick character doing here? Why does this work? I'm happy with the answer but I don't understand why putting those backticks make it work.

Comment: I reverted edit #5 because I also had the error mentioned by @topshot

Comment: @tgonzalez89 the backticks isolate the double quote characters from the backslash characters so that the double quote characters aren't unescaped prematurely.

Answer (score 26):

Using

`#Requires -RunAsAdministrator`

has not been stated, yet. It seems to be there only since PowerShell 4.0.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847765.aspx

> When this switch parameter is added to your requires statement, 
>         it specifies that the Windows PowerShell session in which you are
>         running the script must be started with elevated user rights 
>         (Run as Administrator).

To me, this seems like a good way to go about this, but I'm not sure of the field experience, yet. PowerShell 3.0 runtimes probably ignore this, or even worse, give an error.

When the script is run as a non-administrator, the following error is given:

> The script 'StackOverflow.ps1' cannot be run because it contains a
>   "#requires" statement for running as Administrator. The current
>   Windows  PowerShell session is not running as Administrator. Start
>   Windows PowerShell by  using the Run as Administrator option, and then
>   try running the  script again.
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (StackOverflow.ps1:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptRequiresElevation
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately all it does is make the script fail with an error if shell has no admin privileges. It doesn't elevate by itself.

Comment: PS3 appears to give an error as suggested. I get `Parameter RunAsAdministrator requires an argument`. @akauppi I'm not convinced they always are thinking.

Answer (score 16):

You can easily add some registry entries to get a "Run as administrator" context menu for `.ps1` files:

```
New-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowershellScript.1\Shell\runas\command" `
-Force -Name '' -Value '"c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noexit "%1"'
```

(updated to a simpler script from @Shay)

Basically at `HKCR:\Microsoft.PowershellScript.1\Shell\runas\command` set the default value to invoke the script using Powershell.

Comment: It doesn't work, you're creating a '(default)' key, not updating the '(default)' key value. I was able to condense the code to a one-liner that works for me. Can you test it? New-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowershellScript.1\Shell\runas\command" -Force -Name '' -Value '"c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noexit "%1"'

Comment: @Shay Levy - Hi Shay, thanks for updated one. I have updated the answer with it. It does work. But the one I had worked as well, though it was verbose. I hadn't done much reg edit with Powershell, but doing it with "(default)" was something that I had seen as an example. It did not create a new key ( which something like default would have) but did update the default key as expected. Did you try it out or just guessed from the `(default)` part?

Comment: I tried it. It created a '(default)' key under the command key.

Comment: This worked for me after some minor changes to the registry value:

"c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -NoExit "& '%1'"

Comment: The registry value in the answer has all kinds of problems. It doesn't actually run the command, and it doesn't properly quote the script name (meaning it breaks on paths with spaces). I'm using the following successfully: `"c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noexit  -command "& '%1'"`

Comment: An alternative context-menu command which doesn't use the "runas" key, and which preserves the current directory (see section 2 of the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033941/2441655

Answer (score 14):

The code posted by Jonathan and Shay Levy did not work for me.

Please find the working code below:

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{   
#"No Administrative rights, it will display a popup window asking user for Admin rights"

$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments

break
}
#"After user clicked Yes on the popup, your file will be reopened with Admin rights"
#"Put your code here"
```

Comment: Very useful and pratical solution: just perpended it to my script and it works.

Comment: @Abatonime How about you point out easy to miss differences for the benefit of your readers instead? Honestly, that change isn't worth more than a comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 11):

You need to rerun the script with administrative privileges and check if the script was launched in that mode. Below I have written a script that has two functions: *DoElevatedOperations* and *DoStandardOperations*. You should place your code that requires admin rights into the first one and standard operations into the second. The *IsRunAsAdmin* variable is used to identify the admin mode.

My code is an simplified extract from the Microsoft script that is automatically generated when you create an app package for Windows Store apps.

```
param(
    [switch]$IsRunAsAdmin = $false
)

# Get our script path
$ScriptPath = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value.MyCommand.Path

#
# Launches an elevated process running the current script to perform tasks
# that require administrative privileges.  This function waits until the
# elevated process terminates.
#
function LaunchElevated
{
    # Set up command line arguments to the elevated process
    $RelaunchArgs = '-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "' + $ScriptPath + '" -IsRunAsAdmin'

    # Launch the process and wait for it to finish
    try
    {
        $AdminProcess = Start-Process "$PsHome\PowerShell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $RelaunchArgs -PassThru
    }
    catch
    {
        $Error[0] # Dump details about the last error
        exit 1
    }

    # Wait until the elevated process terminates
    while (!($AdminProcess.HasExited))
    {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    }
}

function DoElevatedOperations
{
    Write-Host "Do elevated operations"
}

function DoStandardOperations
{
    Write-Host "Do standard operations"

    LaunchElevated
}


#
# Main script entry point
#

if ($IsRunAsAdmin)
{
    DoElevatedOperations
}
else
{
    DoStandardOperations
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also force the application to open as administrator, if you have an administrator account, of course.

[image]

Locate the file, *right click > properties > Shortcut > Advanced* and check *Run as Administrator*

Then Click OK.

Comment: How do you script this?

Comment: Something like this... haven't tested it... update with your values `runas /user:\"COMPUTER-NAME\\ADMIN-USER\" \"C:\\PATH\\TO\\PROGRAM.EXE\"`

Answer (score 8):

Adding my 2 cents. My simple version based on net session which works all the time so far in Windows 7 / Windows 10. Why over complicate it?

```
if (!(net session)) {$path =  "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'" ; Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $path ; exit}
```

just add to the top of the script and it will run as administrator.

Comment: is there a way to put a message to the user after the "Access is denied" is displayed?

Comment: ... or to avoid the message at all

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `if (!(net session 2>&1 | Out-Null)) { ... ` @ycomp `... } else { echo "your message" }`.

Comment: getting errors for this, `cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.`

Comment: @user2305193 do what it says

Comment: @AliFurkan Please add more information, it's unclear as how and why you say this, stackoverflow does not typically build on 'authoritarian' arguments

Comment: @user2305193 `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy <PolicyName>`, You can set it to `bypass`

But `bypass` may be dangerous. Set it to `AllSigned`

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is by design. There are multiple layers of security since Microsoft really didn't want .ps1 files to be the latest email virus. Some people find this to be counter to the very notion of task automation, which is fair. The Vista+ security model is to "de-automate" things, thus making the user okay them.

However, I suspect if you launch powershell itself as elevated, it should be able to run batch files without requesting the password again until you close powershell.

Comment: You CANNOT launch PowerShell elevated from the Run Command, unless you run this first:

Answer (score 6):

A number of the answers here are close, but a little more work than needed.

Create a shortcut to your script and configure it to "Run as Administrator":

- Create the shortcut.
- Right-click shortcut and open `Properties...`
- Edit `Target` from `<script-path>` to `powershell <script-path>`
- Click <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> and enable `Run as administrator`

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to run a elevated powershell command and collect its output form within a windows batch file in a single command(i.e not writing a ps1 powershell script).

```
powershell -Command 'Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-Command (Get-Process postgres | Select-Object Path | Select-Object -Index 0).Path | Out-File -encoding ASCII $env:TEMP\camp-postgres.tmp" -Verb RunAs'
```

Above you see i first launch a powershell with elevated prompt and then ask that to launch another powershell(sub shell) to run the command.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a way to do this...

Create a batch file to open your script:

```
@echo off
START "" "C:\Scripts\ScriptName.ps1"
```

Then create a shortcut, on your desktop say (right click *New* -> *Shortcut*).

Then paste this into the location:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:*DOMAIN*\*ADMIN USERNAME* C:\Scripts\BatchFileName.bat
```

When first opening, you will have to enter your password once. This will then save it in the Windows credential manager.

After this you should then be able to run as administrator without having to enter a administrator username or password.

Comment: /savecred is not safe!

Comment: This is the only solution that doesn't use the graphical elevation prompt that might not be accessible on a remote session.

Answer (score 4):

`C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell` is where the **shortcut** of PowerShell resides. It too still goes to a different location to invoke the actual 'exe' (`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`).

Since PowerShell is user-profile driven when permissions are concerned; if your username/profile has the permissions to do something then under that profile, in PowerShell you would generally be able to do it as well. That being said, it would make sense that you would alter the shortcut located under your user profile, for example, `C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell`.

Right-click and click properties. Click "Advanced" button under the "Shortcut" tab located right below the "Comments" text field adjacent to the right of two other buttons, "Open File Location" and "Change Icon", respectively.

Check the checkbox that reads, "Run as Administrator". Click <kbd>OK</kbd>, then <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>. Once again right click the icon labeled 'Windows PowerShell' located in `C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell` and select "Pin to Start Menu/Taskbar".

Now whenever you click that icon, it will invoke the [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) for escalation. After selecting 'YES', you will notice the PowerShell console open and it will be labeled "Administrator" on the top of the screen.

To go a step further... you could right click that same icon shortcut in your profile location of Windows PowerShell and assign a keyboard shortcut that will do the exact same thing as if you clicked the recently added icon. So where it says "Shortcut Key" put in a keyboard key/button combination like: **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + P<kbd>P</kbd> (for PowerShell)**. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Now all you have to do is press that button combination you assigned and you will see UAC get invoked, and after you select 'YES' you will see a PowerShell console appear and "Administrator" displayed on the title bar.

Comment: Dude :) The keyword in OP's question is scripting!! Not some UI mouse clicking solution.

Answer (score 4):

I am using the solution below. It handles stdout/stderr via transcript feature and passes exit code correctly to parent process. You need to adjust transcript path/filename.

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{ 
  echo "* Respawning PowerShell child process with elevated privileges"
  $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
  $pinfo.FileName = "powershell"
  $pinfo.Arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  $pinfo.Verb = "RunAs"
  $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $false
  $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $false
  $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $true
  $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
  $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
  $p.Start() | Out-Null
  $p.WaitForExit()
  echo "* Child process finished"
  type "C:/jenkins/transcript.txt"
  Remove-Item "C:/jenkins/transcript.txt"
  Exit $p.ExitCode
} Else {
  echo "Child process starting with admin privileges"
  Start-Transcript -Path "C:/jenkins/transcript.txt"
}

# Rest of your script goes here, it will be executed with elevated privileges
```

Comment: This loses all invocation arguments

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the [@pgk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11440595/2160765) and [@Andrew Odri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872686/2160765)'s answers is when you have script parameters, specially when they are mandatory. You can solve this problem using the following approach:

1. The user right-clicks the *.ps1* file and selects 'Run with PowerShell': ask him for the parameters through input boxes (this is a much better option than use the *HelpMessage* parameter attribute);
2. The user executes the script through the console: allow him to pass the desired parameters and let the console force him to inform the mandatory ones.

Here is how would be the code if the script had the *ComputerName* and *Port* mandatory parameters:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName='RunWithPowerShellContextMenu')]
param (
    [parameter(ParameterSetName='CallFromCommandLine')]
    [switch] $CallFromCommandLine,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='RunWithPowerShellContextMenu')]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='CallFromCommandLine')]
    [string] $ComputerName,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='RunWithPowerShellContextMenu')]
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='CallFromCommandLine')]
    [UInt16] $Port
)

function Assert-AdministrativePrivileges([bool] $CalledFromRunWithPowerShellMenu)
{
    $isAdministrator = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)

    if ($isAdministrator)
    {
        if (!$CalledFromRunWithPowerShellMenu -and !$CallFromCommandLine)
        {
            # Must call itself asking for obligatory parameters
            & "$PSCommandPath" @script:PSBoundParameters -CallFromCommandLine
            Exit
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!$CalledFromRunWithPowerShellMenu -and !$CallFromCommandLine)
        {
            $serializedParams = [Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($script:PSBoundParameters)

            $scriptStr = @"
                `$serializedParams = '$($serializedParams -replace "'", "''")'

                `$params = [Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize(`$serializedParams)

                & "$PSCommandPath" @params -CallFromCommandLine
"@

            $scriptBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($scriptStr)
            $encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($scriptBytes)

            # If this script is called from another one, the execution flow must wait for this script to finish.
            Start-Process -FilePath 'powershell' -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand" -Verb 'RunAs' -Wait
        }
        else
        {
            # When you use the "Run with PowerShell" feature, the Windows PowerShell console window appears only briefly.
            # The NoExit option makes the window stay visible, so the user can see the script result.
            Start-Process -FilePath 'powershell' -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoExit -File ""$PSCommandPath""" -Verb 'RunAs'
        }

        Exit
    }
}

function Get-UserParameters()
{
    [string] $script:ComputerName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter a computer name:', 'Testing Network Connection')

    if ($script:ComputerName -eq '')
    {
        throw 'The computer name is required.'
    }

    [string] $inputPort = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter a TCP port:', 'Testing Network Connection')

    if ($inputPort -ne '')
    {
        if (-not [UInt16]::TryParse($inputPort, [ref]$script:Port))
        {
            throw "The value '$inputPort' is invalid for a port number."
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw 'The TCP port is required.'
    }
}

# $MyInvocation.Line is empty in the second script execution, when a new powershell session
# is started for this script via Start-Process with the -File option.
$calledFromRunWithPowerShellMenu = $MyInvocation.Line -eq '' -or $MyInvocation.Line.StartsWith('if((Get-ExecutionPolicy')

Assert-AdministrativePrivileges $calledFromRunWithPowerShellMenu

# Necessary for InputBox
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') | Out-Null

if ($calledFromRunWithPowerShellMenu)
{
    Get-UserParameters
}

# ... script code
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Port $Port
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler solution is that you may also right click on "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" and choose "Run as Administrator" then you can run any app as administrator without providing any password.

Answer (score 2):

I recently needed this to build an environment on ansible. I say right away - the decision is not mine, but I don’t remember where I got it. Looks like that:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command Get-Service -Name ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic' -Verb RunAs}";
```

This example enables ssh-agent autostart.
The required command is specified after -Command. The only problem is the launch happens on a new PS instance, but so far this is the only way that I know to execute the command as an admin without additional steps.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way I've found is to wrap it in a self-elevating .bat file:

```
@echo off
NET SESSION 1>NUL 2>NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO ADMINTASKS
CD %~dp0
MSHTA "javascript: var shell = new ActiveXObject('shell.application'); shell.ShellExecute('%~nx0', '', '', 'runas', 0); close();"
EXIT

:ADMINTASKS

powershell -file "c:\users\joecoder\scripts\admin_tasks.ps1"

EXIT
```

The .bat checks if you're already admin and relaunches the script as Administrator if needed.  It also prevents extraneous "cmd" windows from opening with the 4th parameter of `ShellExecute()` set to `0`.

Comment: Good answer, but I tried it and didn't work (and exited the command line from which I called it). I fixed this way: I changed the first `EXIT` to a `GOTO :EOF` and deleted the second. Also, the `cd %~dp0` should be `cd /d %~dp0` AND placed the first command after the `@echo off`. This way you don't need the absolute path of the `.ps1` either, just place it in the same folder that the `.bat`. If you need to see the result, change the 4th parameter to `1`.

Comment: Which O/S and version are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate. I have system in C: but also data and portable applications in D: mainly (and several other drives). By the way... what if the program/script use parameters? What would be the `mshta` command?

Comment: I think you may have errored in your testing, because the script works just fine.  By the way, it's designed to exit the calling `cmd` process so that's not "fixing" it, but I'm glad you were able to modify it according to your needs.

Comment: Ok if you want to exit the `cmd` (I didn't). But regarding the other changes, I think are fixes because my version would work for both of us while yours doesn't for me, i.e. mine's more general (address the scenario of different drives). Anyway, a very clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

Existing answers lacked arguments and working directory passthrough.

Here is my snippet:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
    Write-Host "Running as non-administrator, restarting as administrator..."
    $powershell = if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -gt 5) { "pwsh.exe" } else { "powershell.exe" }
    $arguments = ($PsBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "-$($_.Key) `"$($_.Value)`"" }) -join " "
    Start-Process $powershell  -WorkingDirectory (Get-Location) -Verb RunAs -Wait "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`" $arguments"; exit 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of Shay Levy's answer, follow the below setup (just once)

1. Start a PowerShell with Administrator rights.
2. Follow Stack Overflow question *[PowerShell says “execution of scripts is disabled on this system.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/4038991#4038991)*.
3. Put your .ps1 file in any of the `PATH` folders, for example. Windows\System32 folder

After the setup:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Invoke `powershell Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs <ps1_file>`

You can now run everything in just one command line. The above works on Windows 8 Basic 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen my own way of doing it before, so, try this out. It is way easier to follow and has a much smaller footprint:

```
if([bool]([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).Groups -notcontains "S-1-5-32-544") {
    Start Powershell -ArgumentList "& '$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path'" -Verb runas
    }
```

Very simply, if the current Powershell session was called with administrator privileges, the Administrator Group well-known SID will show up in the Groups when you grab the current identity. Even if the account is a member of that group, the SID won't show up unless the process was invoked with elevated credentials.

Nearly all of these answers are a variation on Microsoft's Ben Armstrong's immensely popular method of how to accomplish it while not really grasping what it is actually doing and how else to emulate the same routine.

Answer (score 0):

To append the output of the command to a text filename which includes the current date you can do something like this:

```
$winupdfile = 'Windows-Update-' + $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy) + '.txt'
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\$winupdfile -Append`"" -Verb RunAs; exit } else { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\$winupdfile -Append`""; exit }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a clarification ...

The powershell RUNAS / SAVECRED credential "is not safe", tried it and it adds the admin identity and password into the credential cache and can be used elsewhere OOPS!. If you have done this I suggest you check and remove the entry.

Review your program or code because the Microsoft policy is you cannot have mixed user and admin code in the same code blob without the UAC (the entry point) to execute the program as admin. This would be sudo (same thing) on Linux.

The UAC has 3 types, dont'see, a prompt or an entry point generated in the manifest of the program. It does not elevate the program so if there is no UAC and it needs admin it will fail. The UAC though as an administrator requirement is good, it prevents code execution without authentication and prevents the mixed codes scenario executing at user level.

Comment: This should be a comment, it is not a solution to the question (just the way the forum works; your content is useful, but is not a solution).

Answer (score 0):

**Elevated PowerShell from Start>Run**

You cannot run elevated powershell from the "run" command, in 2012R2 or 2016, without shelling twice:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell -Command "saps PowerShell -Verb RunAs "

Answer (score -2):

It turns out it was too easy. All you have to do is run a cmd as administrator. Then type `explorer.exe` and hit enter. That opens up [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer).
Now right click on your PowerShell script that you want to run, choose "run with PowerShell" which will launch it in PowerShell in administrator mode.

It may ask you to enable the policy to run, type Y and hit enter. Now the script will run in PowerShell as administrator. In case it runs all red, that means your policy didn't take affect yet. Then try again and it should work fine.

Comment: Not sure what version of Windows you're running, but on Windows 10, at least, invoking explorer.exe from an elevated command prompt won't open an elevated explorer process, unless you terminate all currently-running explorer processes first.

Comment: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell -Command "saps PowerShell -Verb RunAs "