# running a bat file and powershell with elevated priviliges

Tags: powershell, batch-file, elevated-privileges

so i have a bat file that goes:
    powershell -noexit "My\file\location\myscript.ps1"

the bat file is in the start up.  the powershell script changes the bcd.  when executed in this manner it says i do not have privileges, access denied, and nothing in the bcd is changed.

sorry for being a newb, but is there a way to pass an elevated privileges value from the bat to the powershell script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible to do from outside Power Shell but it can be done from inside. It's hacky but you could run a power shell script from your bat file that then launches the admin Power Shell session using "PS> Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs".

[PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)

Comment: Yes, it can be done from outside powershell, because you can invoke powershell.exe from cmd with a command. Here's what I normally do to start an elevated PowerShell session from the Run box, which should work just as well from a batch file: `powershell start -verb runas powershell`

Comment: Ok, did you get this working? Did you try "powershell start -verb runas /user:administrator"?