# Powershell incorrectly returning 'invalid argument' error

Tags: c#, powershell, lync

I'm working on a program that needs to connect to a lync trusted app pool and execute a variety of tasks. This is the installer, where I'm setting up the pool, the app, and basically getting all my ducks in a row.

I'm able to create the app pool with the code below:

```
        var cmd = string.Format("new-csTrustedApplicationPool -Identity {0} -Registrar {1} -Site {2} -ComputerFqdn {3}", txtPoolIdentity.Text, registrar, site, localhost);

        try
        {
            _ps.Commands.Clear();
            _ps.AddScript(cmd);
            _ps.Invoke();

            if (_ps.Streams.Error.Any())
            {
                foreach (var errorRecord in _ps.Streams.Error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(errorRecord.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Trusted Application Pool {0} created", txtPoolIdentity.Text));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //Handling code
        }
```

As I said, that works fine. However, when I try to execute the following code, the process fails with an 'invalid argument' error.

```
try
        {
            _ps.Commands.Clear();
            _ps.AddScript("enable-CSTopology");
            _ps.Invoke();
            if (_ps.Streams.Error.Any())
            {
                foreach (var errorRecord in _ps.Streams.Error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(errorRecord.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             //handling code
        }
```

Except "enable-CsTopology" takes no arguments. I've googled around, but I'm not getting any traction here.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does the exception's StackTrace property point to a line number in your code?

Comment: Keith: no, this is a powershell exception that I'm catching from Powershell.Streams.Error.Any.

Comment: And that Error stream is cleared from any other transaction before you invoke the enable-cstopology command?  If so, don't convert the errorRecord ToString.  Break at that point and inspect the errorRecord object to see what other information is in it.  Never know, there might be something useful there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling intensely stupid, I later discovered that the PS object wasn't running with elevated privileges, which caused the topology change to fail. Using the powershell command found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator) solved the issue for me.