# Powershell launch cmd file as administrator

Tags: file, powershell, cmd

I want to execute a `.cmd` file on a remote server, through Powershell. This works well:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <computerName> -credential $cred -ScriptBlock {&"C:\...\Script.cmd"}
```

But what is the syntax to run `Script.cmd` "as administrator" ?

Comment: $cred has the credentials for the remote machine. Did you specify administrator in $cred?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script block should be:

```
-Scriptblock {Start-Process -Path "C:\...\Script.cmd" -Verb Runas}
```

Check out the [Start-Process cmdlet and the verb runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx), that will get you there. Optionally, include `-wait` with that cmdlet to wait for the cmd to finish before returning.