# How to enter text into an input field through Power Shell?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, powershell, scripting

Here is a PowerShell script to trigger Internet Explorer, open LinkedIn login page and enter some text in the username text field.

```
$ie = New-Object -Com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("www.linkedIn.com")
$ie.Visible = $true

$doc = $ie.document
$usernameElement = $doc.getElementByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.id = "session_key-login""}
$usernameElement.Click()

Get-Process iexplore | Foreach-Object {$_.CloseMainWindow()}
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Pinku\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:7 char:23
+ $usernameElement.Click <<<< ()
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Click:String) [], RuntimeExcepti 
on
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I have tried but have not been able to alleviate myself from this issue.Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$doc.getElementsByTagName("input")` and then trying to filter through the results, try retrieving the ID directly using `getElementById`:

```
$usernameElement = $doc.getElementById("session_key-login")
$usernameElement.Click()
```

---Edit---

Response to still getting the `null-valued expression` after using the above:

The error message is that it can't find any elements called "session_key-login", and so it returns $null, and hence, when you try to invoke the `Click()` method, it throws the error. Some things to try:

-Check to see if the id exists. Run the following code after creating your $ie object, and see if there is an ID that matches "session_key-login":

```
$ie = New-Object -Com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("www.linkedIn.com")
$ie.Visible = $true

$doc = $ie.document
$doc.getElementsByTagName("Input") | Select Id, Name
```

-Try running your PowerShell session as Administrator. I know I wasn't able to launch IE properly until I ran PowerShell as Administrator. For ex. even though the iexplore process was created, the physical Internet Explorer window didn't open for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but I have already tried your solution. I still get the same error.

Comment: I get this post your suggestion-`You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Pinku\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:6 char:45
+ $usernameElement = $doc.getElementsByTagName <<<< ("Input") | Select Id, Name
+ CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (getElementsByTagName:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Pinku\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:7 char:23
+ $usernameElement.Click <<<< ()
+ CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (Click:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`

Comment: Sorry but I am still not clear how to run my script as Administrator. I read to run as admin, I need to write `Start-Process powershell -verb runas -ArgumentList "-file fullpathofthescript"` in my script but then multiple windows open.. :(

Comment: Typically you Right-Click on the PowerShell shortcut and select "Run as Administrator". (If you need to run it from a script see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator). Also, run each line of the example I gave in a PowerShell prompt (not from a .PS1 file) so that you can see what is happening (i.e. does Internet explorer actually show up for you? i.e. if IE is not showing up, then the next line: `$doc = $ie.document` will not work, so the issue is with launching the IE process.)