# axbuild.exe nonInteractive | AX 2012 R3

Tags: powershell, compilation, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to execute axbuild.exe ( new 64-bit compiler for Dynamics AX ) via powershell in noninteractive mode and it loads the first screen but then the process ends.

When running from windows command line, the first screen opens, closes, and then a few seconds later a number of worker processes spawn and process the entire X++ compile.

Any thoughts?? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having troubles with `Start-Process` (with elevated privileges), but recently I switched to the `&` command and it runs like a charm, this way:

```
$axBuild = Join-Path $axServerBin "\AxBuild.exe"
$axCompiler = Join-Path $axServerBin "\ax32serv.exe"
& $axBuild 'xppcompileall' /compiler="$axCompiler" /log="$scriptPath" /altbin="$axClientbin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the `axbuild.exe` with elevated privileges (Run as Administrator).

If you are starting the caller process from the *Task Scheduler* you have to tick the *Run with highest privileges* option.

[image: Task Scheduler - Run with highest privileges]

---

Within the powershell you can execute `Start-Process AxBuild.exe -Verb RunAs`.

You can verify *Administrator* privilege with the next code snippet:

```
([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
```

See [PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11440595/117965) for example.

Comment: I'm running this in TeamCity, does it require anything additional? It is executing the following:
Starting:  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell2280810545960782468.ps1"

Comment: The same script works great when I run it manually on the same machine as the same user, with the -Verb RunAs.  But even with that extra switch in the script, it won't work when run via TeamCity.