# How to run Power shell as Administrator

Tags: c#, powershell

My codes runs perfectly when i run it as Admin. but it gave an error when i run it as guest:

> An internal error occurred.

Is there any way i can configure to run power shell as Admin programmatic?

```
string shellUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
string password = "****";
System.Security.SecureString securePW = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
        securePW.AppendChar(c);
securePW.MakeReadOnly();
string domainAndUsername = @"192.168.1.113\***";
string remoteMachineName = "****";
PSCredential remoteCredential = new PSCredential(domainAndUsername, securePW);
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, remoteMachineName, 5985, "/wsman", shellUri, remoteCredential);

using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)) //_Error Here_//
```

I found some solutions but they are OLD, they don't work anymore :S

Comment: does this stackoverflow post answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator

Comment: Maybe you can just create a Windows Scheduled Task that executes the PowerShell script and have it run with a specific user account that has Admin permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Process you can run as admin using below:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell")
            {
                UseShellExecute = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Verb = "runas",
                //UserName = username,
                //Password = MakeSecureString(password)
            };
            var exec = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
            exec?.WaitForExit(0);
```

If you don't want prompt, then you will have to change UAC. And you can pass arguments to process object.