# vmware workstation 15 player: Device/Credential Guard not compatible issue even disable it

Tags: windows, windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation

My host is running Windows 10 enterprise. I got the vmware workstation 15 player issue: Device/Credential Guard not compatible issue when launching a VM.

[image]

I googled and and I followed the instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-manage on disabling the device/credential guard, but still not working. I also tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGpv2Dvzyeg and it's the same issue. I read the stackoverflow posts related to this issue like [VMware Workstation and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858200/vmware-workstation-and-device-credential-guard-are-not-compatible) but still does not help.

Any ideas why? I have no idea what to do next. Please help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VMware Workstation and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858200/vmware-workstation-and-device-credential-guard-are-not-compatible)

Comment: uninstall Hyper-V

Answer (score 1):

On my windows 10 1903 may 2019 update system with vmware player 15.1.0 [ or workstation ] installed i'll get this error from time to time when attempting to start vmplayer.exe [ or vmware.exe ].

The reason is not because of a device/credential guard compatibility issue that was resolved in earlier vmware player and workstation releases.  The reason is because i've forgotten to reboot system with the hyperv-v hypervisor disabled at boot.

As was noted in comments to your question by @magicandre1981 one solution is to uninstall the hyper-v feature and reboot. An alternative, especially if you need hyper-v at other times for vm or docker containers or phone emulator purpose,s is to just temporarily disable its hypervisor component.

This is accomplished using commands that have been been mentioned in other SO threads on this subject that must be run from a "Run as administrator" command prompt or powershell command line window.

```
hyper-v hypervisor disable = bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
hyper-v hypervisor enable = bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
check if hyper-v hypervisor is enabled at boot = bcdedit /enum
```

The last command will show `hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto` when its enabled at boot and `hypervisorlaunchtype    Off` when its disabled which is the state you need to use vmware player [ or workstation ].

If you are someone who maintains an open customized "Run as administrator" command prompt or powershell command line window at all the time you can optionally setup the following aliases / macros to simplify executing the above commands.

```
doskey hpvEnb = choice /c:yn /cs /d n /t 30 /m "Are you running from elevated command prompt" ^& if not errorlevel 2 ( bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto ^& echo.^&echo now reboot to enable hyper-v hypervisor )
doskey hpvDis = choice /c:yn /cs /d n /t 30 /m "Are you running from elevated command prompt" ^& if not errorlevel 2 ( bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off ^& echo.^&echo now reboot to disable hyper-v hypervisor )
doskey bcdL = bcdedit /enum ^& echo.^&echo now see boot configuration data store {current} boot loader settings
```

With the above in place you just type "hpvenb" [ hypervisor enabled at boot ], "hpvdis" [ hypervisor disabled at boot ] and "bcdl" [ boot configuration devices list ] commands to execute the on, off, list commands.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to run virtual mac. i did this two step.
1_ turned off  windows features "Hyper-v" and "virtual machine platform" and "windows hypervisor platform" and restarted windows.
2_ installed last version Mac OS X Unlocker for VMware.

Answer (score 0):

As in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44306227/1454173), simply run this in cmd as administrator and then **reboot**

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had VMware Workstation 15.5.4 and Windwos 10 version 1909 and installed Docker Desktop.

This is because Hyper-V is incompatible with VMware until 2020.

Here how I solved it:

1. Install new VMware Workstation 16.1.0
2. Update my Windwos 10 from 1909 to 20H2

As VMware Guide said in this [link](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146361):

> If your Host has Windows 10 20H1 build 19041.264 or newer,
> upgrade/update to Workstation 15.5.6 or above. If your Host has
> Windows 10 1909 or earlier, disable Hyper-V on the host to resolve
> this issue.

Now VMware and Hyper-V can be at the same time and have both Docker and VMware at my Windows.