# wmware workstation don't work with windows 10 pro 1903

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I have updated Windows 10 PRO to 1903. Reinstalling VMware Workstation and setting existing virtual machine when i run it give me this error:

"VMware Workstation and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible. VMware Workstation can be run after disabling Device/Credential Guard."

I have done it. And i have looked too here:

http://www.vmware.com/go/turnoff_CG_DG

But nothing to do. Not solved. 
So i ask your how i can solve it.
Thanks

Comment: This also happens after the 20.04 update

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solved my problem (run from command prompt, as admin..)

> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

and reboot windows..

Comment: Worked straight away, this should be added in the VMWare troubleshoot link as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had VMware Workstation 15.5.4 and Windwos 10 Pro version 1909 and installed Docker Desktop.

Here how I solved it:

1- Install new VMware Workstation 16.1.0

2- Update my Windwos 10 from 1909 to 20H2

As VMware Guide said in this link: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146361

> If your Host has Windows 10 20H1 build 19041.264 or newer,
> upgrade/update to Workstation 15.5.6 or above. If your Host has
> Windows 10 1909 or earlier, disable Hyper-V on the host to resolve
> this issue.

Now VMware and Hyper-V can be at the same time and have both Docker and WMware at my Windows

Similar question is answered here:
[VMware Workstation and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858200/vmware-workstation-and-device-credential-guard-are-not-compatible/65459105#65459105)