# VMWare error: VMware Player and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player, ubuntu-19.10

I've been running ubuntu 19 (64 bit) on VMWare Workstation 15 Player for 2 months now. There was no problem in running the virtual machine till now, but today when I tried running the machine, it gave me the following error:
`VMware Player and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible. VMware Player can be run after disabling Device/Credential Guard. Please visit http://www.vmware.com/go/turnoff_CG_DG for more details.`
Following are the screenshots for the error:
[Error regarding device credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqfkx.jpg)
[Error code after returning to home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRxZb.jpg)

I followed the link provided by the dialog box, but it was of no use to me. After searching for a while, I found out that **Hyper V** could not be installed in my computer as I have Windows 10 Home version, and hence I could not find anything regarding device credentials on my computer.

Is there any solution that can be useful, other than uninstalling my VM or VMWare player?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue when hyper-v in windows was turned on for docker. I followed this link to fix the issue:

[wmware workstation don't work with windows 10 pro 1903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324278/wmware-workstation-dont-work-with-windows-10-pro-1903)

Comment: But that's the problem that I'm facing. I have Windows 10 Home, which does not even support hyper-v. All the solutions that I've seen are related to hyper-v and windows 10 pro/enterprise. And since this error is related to hyper-v, I don't know what could've possibly gone wrong. I even tried re-installing my VMWare Player. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had VMware Workstation 15.5.4 and Windwos 10 version 1909 and installed Docker Desktop.

This is because Hyper-V is incompatible with VMware until 2020.

Here how I solved it:

1. Install new VMware Workstation 16.1.0
2. Update my Windwos 10 from 1909 to 20H2

As VMware Guide said in this [link](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146361):

> If your Host has Windows 10 20H1 build 19041.264 or newer,
> upgrade/update to Workstation 15.5.6 or above. If your Host has
> Windows 10 1909 or earlier, disable Hyper-V on the host to resolve
> this issue.

**PS: My Windows is Pro but in the VMware Guid it not mentioned only for Windows Pro.**

Now VMware and Hyper-V can be at the same time and have both Docker and VMware at my Windows

Similar question is answered here:
[VMware Workstation and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858200/vmware-workstation-and-device-credential-guard-are-not-compatible/65459105#65459105)