# Difference between Hyper-v and Windows Hypervisor Platform API?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hyper-v, hypervisor

I have **Windows 10 Home Edition**, and I tried to enable the Hyper-v feature.
Upon going through the Microsoft Documentation for the same I realized that  Hyper-v is not functional on Home versions of the OS.

Nonetheless I went to the **Program and Features** interface and looked through the available features:

> *I noticed there was a feature called Windows Hypervisor Platform*.

So I checked it, got it installed and  I rebooted the system. But I still don't know how Hyper-v differs from the Windows Hypervisor Platform API.

I went through the Microsoft Documentation on this one, but it was a bit too sparse and difficult to understand for a beginner like me.I tried to search online, but I didn't find anything significant that clarified the difference.

Can I get a clearer picture of the difference between that two features, and how I can use the Windows Hypervisor Platform to run my own **VMs**?

Does the activation of the Windows Hypervisor Platform API is a prerequisite for running some  3rd party hypervisor software
?

Comment: The [Hyper-V platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/virtualization/api/) is way to enable [coexistence of several hypervisor tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39867169/1466046) and all tools now use Hyper-V .

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Hypervisor Platform is an API that lets other companies use the Windows hypervisor capabilities. For example, a type 2 hypervisor is able to work with this features.
[Microsoft Virtualization Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).