# How to co-exist Hyper-V(WSL2) and VMware?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

envirenment:

- Windows 10 pro 20H2
- VMware® Workstation 16 Pro

vmware error tips:
`"VMware Workstation and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible" error in VMware Workstation on Windows 10 host。"`

I tryed disable "Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Guard > Virtualization Based Security.", but it doesn't work still.

reference:

- https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/05/vmware-workstation-now-supports-hyper-v-mode.html
- [VMware Workstation and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858200/vmware-workstation-and-device-credential-guard-are-not-compatible)