# How to self elevate Powershell script

Tags: powershell

Where and how do I make this script prompt users enter elevated credentials.
i would like to have it so anyone who opens the file gets prompted to elevate the script before it runs

```
    Clear-Host
#Variable for where the E-Billing files are downloaded
$FilePath = "\\LNAPPS\APPS\Finance\eBilling Hub Workstation Configuration\eBillingHub\utils"

#Test if the path exists
$TestPath = Test-Path $FilePath

#If $filepath exists, execute the following files
if 
($TestPath -eq $true) 
{
    Write-Host "Path exists" -ForegroundColor Green
    Start-Process -FilePath "$FilePath\addper.bat"
    Start-Process -FilePath "$FilePath\AddToTrustedSites.reg" 
    Start-Process -FilePath "$FilePath\DotNetPermissions.reg"
}
#If path doesn't exist, write error message
Else
{
    Write-Host "Path not found" | Write-Error
    Exit
}

Write-Host "Configuration complete" -ForegroundColor Blue
```

Comment: i've literally googled your question. this is the first hit: https://blog.expta.com/2017/03/how-to-self-elevate-powershell-script.html what have you tried so far? what did not work? what was the error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self Elevating Script + Execution Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207676/self-elevating-script-execution-policy)

Answer (score -1):

There are different way to accomplish this.
The simplest way is to require the user to already be an admin in order to run it.
Just add this comment in the script to alert the user if elevated permissions is missing

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

If you'd like a little bit of more interaction, then check the elevation your self using

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")){
        throw 'Admin permission missing!' #or anything else you like
    }
```

and then add appropriate code.