# How to set an executable to run with administrator rights in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need a help

I have trouble to set a script in powershell that give DOMAIN adminsitrator rights to an User to an executable . Because I need to install a program in many desktops, plus I need to check if the program is already installed.

This seams to be easy but I know how to program in shell script not much powershell.

```
$SPAdmin = "DOMAIN\ADMIN" 
$Password="FooBoo"|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $SPAdmin, $Password 

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName "Server" -Filter "Name='ServiceName'" -Credential $Credential

$name = "CagService"

   if (Get-Service $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {   
     Write-Host "O Servico do Agente conhecido como $name ja esta Instalado na Maquina com Hostname: $env:computername"
     sleep 5
    }
    Else
    {
            $storageDir = $pwd
            $source = "https://source"
            $destination = "$storageDir\agent.exe"

            Invoke-WebRequest $source -OutFile $destination

            $exec = New-Object -com shell.application
            $exec.shellexecute($destination);
    }
```

Comment: "that give adminsitrator rights to an executable" - executables don't have rights, *accounts* have rights.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen's comment is entirely correct. I would add that if you are asking if it is possible to bypass the UAC prompt in script, the answer is "no, you can't."

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, no I don't want to by pass, yes thanks friend users have rights not an executable, how to make an admin run an executable file from another account using powershell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)

Comment: If you are looking for running under a different account, you might want to use [PSexec from SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason that you can't simply do:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```

From a PS console? That launches a new ps window with admin privileges....

[PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)

Comment: Hi but I want as a Domain Administrator.

Comment: Then you need to put in credentials. You can't use a domain admin account without putting in credentials and even if you save your DA password as a secure string, that string has to be saved on the computer that is using the credentials.

Comment: "but I want as a Domain Administrator" - why?