# User Administration windows 7,10

Tags: windows, powershell, administration, usergroups

I have account within Administators group

The  code Powershell  ( and  .NET  as well )

```
(new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole("Administrators")
```

returns `false`

---

I ran command

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups
```

in 2  cases  under my account and  Powershell as Administrative

and  found  that Powershell as Administrative  has 4 more roles

```
Powershell as Administrative

    BinaryLength AccountDomainSid              Value
    -- ----------------                        -----
    12                                         S-1-1-0
    12                                         S-1-5-114      - Extra
    28 S-1-5-21-573147726-3479669810-588349159 S-1-5-21-573147726-3479669810-588349159-1001
    16                                         S-1-5-32-544   - Extra
    16                                         S-1-5-32-551   - Extra
    16                                         S-1-5-32-559
    16                                         S-1-5-32-547   - Extra
    16                                         S-1-5-32-545
    12                                         S-1-5-4
    12                                         S-1-2-1
    12                                         S-1-5-11
    12                                         S-1-5-15
    52                                         S-1-11-96-3623454863-58364-18864-2661722203-1597581903-24264218...
    12                                         S-1-5-113
    12                                         S-1-2-0
    16                                         S-1-5-64-36


Powershell as Me
    BinaryLength AccountDomainSid              Value
    -- --------------------------              -----
    12                                         S-1-1-0
    28 S-1-5-21-573147726-3479669810-588349159 S-1-5-21-573147726-3479669810-588349159-1001
    16                                         S-1-5-32-559
    16                                         S-1-5-32-545
    12                                         S-1-5-4
    12                                         S-1-2-1
    12                                         S-1-5-11
    12                                         S-1-5-15
    52                                         S-1-11-96-3623454863-58364-18864-2661722203-1597581903-24264218...
    12                                         S-1-5-113
    12                                         S-1-2-0
    16                                         S-1-5-64-36
```

Question :
How can I set my account as truly admin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the account, by default all applications are run without administrator privilege due to UAC.  Right-click on Powershell and select the "Run as administrator" option to run Powershell with elevated privileges.