# Restart-Computer Access Denied Error

Tags: powershell

I'm currently creating a PowerShell script who need to be able to rename computer name:

```
Write-Host "Enter the new computer name: " -NoNewline
$name = Read-Host
Rename-Computer -NewName $name
```

And when I execute this code I got this error, even if I start the script with Administrator rights, I get the same error.

> Rename-Computer : The computer "LAPTOP-ASVDNCPD" could not be renamed to "[new_computer_name]" because of the following exception: Access Denied.

Comment: Is the computer domain joined?

Comment: No, the computer is not into a domain. And I don't want to join a domain.

Comment: Try adding a `-LocalCredential Srvname\Administrator -Force -PassThru` into the same command; it should work! Check here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Is the account you're running the script as (likely that you're logged on with) a member of the Administrators group? You will also need to elevate PowerShell ('Run as Administrator').

Comment: @JamesC. Yes, it is in Administrators group. But after, I want to run the script by righ clicking and "Execute with PowerShell" (or by running bat file)

Comment: You'll need to self elevate the script then: [PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](//stackoverflow.com/q/7690994)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to self elevate the script to run the command as Administrator.
[PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)