# Check elevated process status?

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to find a way to find out if a process is running as elevated or not using Powershell.

Use Case: Being able to run control panel tasks with elevated privilage as local domain user e.g. Add or Remove programs.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
#Start add or remove as admin
start-process appwiz.cpl -verb runas

#Check if path exists. Answer is Yes, so process is NOT elevated
get-wmiobject -class win32_process | select-object -properties name, path
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11440595/3829407 Tempting dupe but the question is different. That shows how to run elevated if not already. The detection algorithm in the linked answer is what you are asking.

Answer (score 8):

These are the two usual options:

1. Use the `#requires -RunAsAdministrator` line in your script (requires PowerShell 3.0 or later). If you use this line at the top of your script, it will throw a terminating error and won't execute if the current process isn't elevated.
2. Use code like the following to detect whether the current process is elevated:

   ```
   $IsElevated = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
   ```