# How to run PowerShell as a administrator programmatically?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to run the PowerShell script through ossec in which I want to used `Set-Acl` command which required administrator privileges. So I want this script run as a administrator programatically.
I used this tag:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs
```

but it asks for user response. so is there another solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)

Comment: @Protozoid That's what he's already doing.

Comment: Configure UAC to not prompt for confirmation from admin accounts or disable it entirely.

Comment: i dont want this asks for user response, the script will handle the same automatically and further code will be run as administrator.

Comment: Please re-read my previous comment.

Comment: actually in ossec i push the script from server to multiple agents pc., which is run by itself. i have not access for any agent. so i cant access UAL of any agant pc.

Comment: I told you what you need to do. If you can't do it yourself you need to find somebody who can do it for you.