# Calling a powershell script with Gradle

Tags: powershell, gradle

I am new to Gradle, so bear with me.. I am simply trying to call a .ps1 file to execute with gradle. How would I go about setting up a build.gradle file to execute the .ps1 file within the same directory? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gradle [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)

Example:

```
task execPs(type:Exec) {
   commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'Powershell  -File  sample.ps1'
}
// add this task to your build.gradle file and execute gradle execPs
// You can use a different name for this task 
// You can add a dependency to include this task as part of your normal build. (like below) 
// build.finalizedBy(execPs)
// with the above command gradle build will call your task at the end of build
```

Comment: This works great! How could I run the powershell script as admin?

Comment: @Stacker create another ps1, which calls your ps script as admin as described here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator  And call this new ps1 from gradle. This would bring up a adminastator popup depending on your windows config.

Comment: One more question.. How can I pass an argument to my powershell script from within gradle.  "Powershell -file sample.ps1 argument" does not work

Comment: But when called with -File option, powershell always returns 0 as exit code even though the script failed.