# Executing file from Admin CMD via CLI

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to execute  a file via the CMD with Administrative privileges.

How can I open a cmd via command line with Administrative privileges.

I have to execute a script within a script.

```
 powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -noprofile -command "&{ start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -File C:\scripts\install_ims.ps1' -verb RunAs}"
```

I have tried this in a bat file, but it doesn't work when executed within the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)

Comment: Why is it that you need to invoke PowerShell twice?

Comment: I am writing these in terraforms @lit.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for your purposes.

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process <filename> -Verb RunAs"
```

This is copy-pasted from some Batch files that I finally added to GitHub in the last few days if you have questions, that's probably the best place to go. https://github.com/Benny121221/Batch-BS