# How to sudo on powershell on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, sudo

Whenever I need to run a powershell script it complains of security, if I add `powershell.exe -nologo -executionpolicy bypass -File .\install.ps1` I still get permission denied unauthorizedAccessException. I just want to run this install script, what is the sudo equivalent to type on the powershell on windows?

Edit:

It's 2024 now and we are getting actual sudo for Windows 11

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-sudo-for-windows/

See the repository for additional details

https://github.com/microsoft/sudo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a command as Administrator using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/running-a-command-as-administrator-using-powershell)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

<sup>**Note**: If you're looking to add *general-purpose*, *prepackaged* `sudo`-like functionality to PowerShell, consider the

`Enter-AdminPSSession` (`psa`) function from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/f726dee9f0d3d444bf58cb81fda57884), discussed in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199970/45375).</sup>

**If you are running *from PowerShell already***, then use `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` as follows:

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe -Args "-executionpolicy bypass -command Set-Location \`"$PWD\`"; .\install.ps1"
```

Note:

- The script invariably runs in a *new window*.
- Since the new window's working directory is invariably `$env:windir\System32`, a `Set-Location` call that switches to the caller's working directory (`$PWD`) is prepended.

  - Note that in PowerShell (Core) 7+ (`pwsh.exe`) this is no longer necessary, because the caller's current location is inherited.
- Executing `Set-Location` necessitates the use of `-Command` instead of `-File`.

  - A general caveat is that `-Command` can change the way arguments passed to your script are interpreted (there are none in your case), because they are interpreted the same way they would be if you passed the arguments from within PowerShell, whereas `-File` treats them as literals.

**If you're calling from *outside of PowerShell***, typically from **`cmd.exe`/ a batch file**, you need to **wrap the above in an *outer call to `powershell.exe`***, which complicates things in terms of quoting, unfortunately:

```
powershell.exe -command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe -Args '-executionpolicy bypass -command', \"Set-Location `\"$PWD`\"; .\install.ps1\""
```

---

**Interactively**, of course, you can:

- Right-click the PowerShell shortcut (in your taskbar or Start Menu, or on your Desktop), select `Run as Administrator` to open a PowerShell window that runs with admin privileges, and run `.\install.ps1` from there.
- Alternatively, from an existing PowerShell window, you can open a run-as-admin window with `Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe`, as in [AdminOfThings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55314594/45375).

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, all others didn't.

Answer (score 50):

As suggested in the question description as well, try out the new [microsoft/sudo](https://github.com/microsoft/sudo)!

If you are using Chocolatey (a package manager), you can install a package named `sudo`.
Then you can use sudo like Linux 
[image: sudo]

Comment: This is great! I can finally use the PowerShell window I always keep open, instead of reaching for PowerShell / Run as Administrator in the Start Menu. :-)

Comment: This works. But I can not see any program output. For example, if I type "sudo ls", it shows an UAC prompt, then just goes to next line of cursor without showing me the output of the "ls" command. I recommend "gsudo" as a better alternative.

Comment: Tried at the end 2021 and it works so good!! I use that for installing choco packages

Comment: I like this. Thanks! very useful

Comment: Unlike Unix, it pops up a confirmation dialog UI on the host, which makes it unusable for using on remote hosts.

Answer (score 9):

You can utilize the [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6) command and then use parameter `-Verb runas` to elevate. This works great for starting an elevated process.

I created a sudo function like this and added it to my powershell profile:

```
function sudo {
    Start-Process @args -verb runas
}
```

**Example**: Open notepad as Admin to edit hosts file

```
sudo notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

If you want to elevate a Powershell command, you can create a simple function like this:

```
function Start-ElevatedPS {
    param([ScriptBlock]$code)

    Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $code
}
```

Then, call the function and pass command wrapped in `{}` (script block)

**Example**: Elevate to create a symbolic link

```
Start-ElevatedPS { New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Name mySymlink.ps1 -Target C:\myTarget.ps1 }
```

Comment: Worth mentioning you can get to this using the $PROFILE variable, `notepad.exe $PROFILE`

Comment: if I run Start-ElevatedPS as follows: `Start-ElevatedPS { New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "$var1" -Target "$var2"; }`, I get an error saying "Cannot bind argument to parameter Path" even though `$var1` and `$var2` are defined right before this call.

Comment: `.$PROFILE` reload profile. Nice snippet, ty

Comment: I added `-ArgumentList "-noexit", $code` so it doesn't exit, this is probably useful to someone.

Comment: I don't know if this used to work and stopped working at some point?
````
sudo choco install python
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'python'.
At C:\Users\<user>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:6 char:5
+     Start-Process @args -verb runas
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
````

Answer (score 7):

As of today (October 2021), `winget install gerardog.gsudo` did the trick (on windows 10 home edition). Edit: Tested on Windows 11 as well (April 2022)

after that, you can do this:

```
gsudo notepad C:\windows\system32\something-editable-by-admin-only.txt
```

To test if it's working, or in your case:

```
gsudo powershell.exe install.ps1
```

You will be prompted by windows` UAC to elevate your priveleges by gsudo, and you can read the source code here: https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo

Answer (score 5):

You can start PowerShell with the Run as Administrator option:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```

Comment: Works great. Running this command inside a Powershell opens a new admin privileged powershell window.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a corporate policy that blocks scripts execution, then yes. ByPass does not change your profile (user context) state. That is not the design (use case) for any of those switches [regarding Execution Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies).

There is not a direct comparison of sudo in Windows, this has nothing to do with PowerShell. You are either admin in a session / app or you are not. If you are installing software, that means you must be admin. If you are doing global system-wide changes, that means you must be admin.

There are folks who have strived to implement scripts, wrapper functions and or modules to mimic sudo …

Module from the MS PowerShell gallery.
[Sudo 0.9.3](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Sudo/0.9.3) 
Use functionality similar to sudo in PowerShell

From GitHub
[Sudo for PowerShell](https://github.com/stephenn/powershell_sudo)

> Sudo for PowerShell Installation From PowerShell, create a $profile if
>   you don't have one:

```
if (!(test-path $profile)) { new-item -path $profile -itemtype file -force }
```

> Open the profile in notepad:

```
notepad.exe $profile
```

> Add the following line and save the file:

```
. /path/to/sudo.ps1
```

> sudo will be available in all new PowerShell windows Usage

```
sudo application [arguments ...]
```

...but that does not change what Windows expects when dealing with security boundaries.

See also this Q&A 
[Sudo !! equivalent in PowerShell](https://serverfault.com/questions/270611/sudo-equivalent-in-powershell)

> $^ is a variable that expands to the last executed Powershell command.
>   You can run a command as another user using runas, so the following
>   works:

```
runas /user:domain\administrator $^
```

> To shorten that up a bit, you can do some magic with aliases. Take a
>   look at this [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347682.aspx) for more info.
>
> EDIT: One caveat - $^ only executes the first command in a pipeline or
>   multi-command line. If you need to redo an entire command that is
>   peppered with pipes or semicolons, use Invoke-History instead (which
>   defaults to the last full command in its entirety).

Comment: I was actually trying to run a script I wrote in a [Windows VM](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines) . The same script ran just fine in AppVeyor, so it was a surprise. :/

Comment: Humm… OK,  then you are in complete control of that VM?  If so, then why is the execution policy restricted? That is the default, but you can change that using Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned, then you have no need for the bypass thing. Local scripts run, remote scripts need to be signed to run. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx

Comment: `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` always works, irrespective of the effective PowerShell execution policy. You can use it to invoke a PowerShell instance that runs `Start-Process -Verb RunAs`, which gives you an elevated process - after confirming / providing admin credentials to a UAC prompt.

Comment: The 2nd project you link to - https://github.com/stephenn/powershell_sudo - is a _minimal_ wrapper around `Start-Process -Verb RunAs`, which requires invocation _from PowerShell_. However, its minimalist nature means that it doesn't address the problem of the working dir. defaulting to `$env:windir\System32` and also not `Start-Process`'s [broken handling of arguments with embedded whitespace](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576). In short: this wrapper is hardly worth it.

Comment: `runas.exe /user:...` will only result in an _elevated_ (run-as-admin) process if you use the _built-in_ `Administrator` account - which is _disabled by default_, for security reasons. `$^` is not the the most recently executed PowerShell _command_, it is only that command's _first token_.

Comment: Correction: [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies#set-a-different-policy-for-one-session) suggest that `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` cannot override a policy _set by a GPO_ (Group Policy Object).

Answer (score -1):

change from https://github.com/steve02081504/esh/blob/218efeae99c557ca0b36b638ff69f8e7683b1abf/src/commands/esh_base.ps1#L9L100

[image: preview]

Pure pwsh

No additional package manager required

Add to profile and it works (maybe,IDK)

Runs the command in a new window if with arguments (and captures the output and displays it in the old window), and starts a new pwsh window with administrator privileges if without arguments

Exactly 90 lines :tada:

```
function global:Test-Command($Command) {
    [bool]$(Get-Command $Command -ErrorAction Ignore)
}
function global:cmd_args_convert($Arguments) {
    ($Arguments | ForEach-Object {
        if (($_.IndexOf('"') -ge 0) -or ($_.IndexOf(' ') -ge 0)) {
            '"' + $_.Replace('"', '"""') + '"'
        } else {$_}
    }) -join ' '
}
function global:pwsh_args_convert($Arguments) {
    ($Arguments | ForEach-Object {
        if (($_.IndexOf('"') -ge 0) -or ($_.IndexOf(' ') -ge 0)) {
            '"' + $_.Replace('"', '`"') + '"'
        } else {$_}
    }) -join ' '
}
# SudoShadow用于将管理员窗口的输出保存到文件中以便在非管理员窗口中显示
function global:__SudoShadow__ {
    param(
        $Command,
        $UUID=$(New-Guid).Guid
    )
    $SudoShadowFile = "$env:Temp/sudo_shadows/$UUID.txt"
    Start-Transcript -Path $SudoShadowFile -UseMinimalHeader | Out-Null
    Invoke-Expression $Command
    Stop-Transcript | Out-Null
    Write-Host "Sudo shadow file was saved to $SudoShadowFile"
}
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
function global:sudo {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)][string[]]$RemainingArguments
    )
    $pwshArguments = "$(if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -gt 7.3){`"-NoProfileLoadTime`"}) -nologo"
    if ($RemainingArguments.Length -eq 0) {
        if ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]“Administrator”) {
            Write-Host "I already have $($VirtualTerminal.Styles.Blink)Super Power$($VirtualTerminal.Styles.NoBlink)s."
        }
        # If the command is empty, open a new PowerShell shell with admin privileges
        elseif (Test-Command wt.exe) {
            Start-Process -Wait -FilePath 'wt.exe' -ArgumentList "pwsh.exe $pwshArguments" -Verb runas
        }
        else {
            Start-Process -Wait -FilePath 'pwsh.exe' -ArgumentList $pwshArguments -Verb runas
        }
    } else {
        if ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]“Administrator”) {
            Invoke-Expression "$RemainingArguments"
            return
        }
        # Otherwise, run the command as an admin
        $UUID=$(New-Guid).Guid
        $ShadowCommand = "__SudoShadow__ -UUID '$UUID' -Command '$(pwsh_args_convert $RemainingArguments)'"
        $baseBinary = 'pwsh.exe'
        if (Test-Command wt.exe) {
            $Arguments = @($baseBinary,'-Command', $ShadowCommand)
            $Arguments = cmd_args_convert $Arguments
            Start-Process -Wait -FilePath 'wt.exe' -ArgumentList $Arguments.Replace('"','\"') -Verb runas
        }
        else {
            $Arguments = @('-Command', $ShadowCommand)
            $Arguments = cmd_args_convert $Arguments
            Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $baseBinary -ArgumentList "$pwshArguments $Arguments" -Verb runas
        }
        try {
            $Shadow=Get-Content "$env:Temp/sudo_shadows/$UUID.txt"
            Remove-Item "$env:Temp/sudo_shadows/$UUID.txt"
            $Shadow = ($Shadow | Select-Object -Skip 4 -SkipLast 4) -join "`n"
            #由于Start-Transcript会将宽字符重复写入，所以对于每一个字符在$Shadow中进行渲染以获取其宽度，去除多余的字符
            $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('cascadia mono', 128)
            $Width = 0
            $ShadowHandled=($Shadow.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {
                if($Width -eq 0) {
                    $Width = [Math]::Max([Math]::Floor(
                        [System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer]::MeasureText($_, $Font).Width/
                    128)-1,0)
                }
                elseif($_ -eq $LastChar) { $Width--;return }
                else{ $UseOriginal = $true }
                $LastChar = $_;$_
            }) -join ''
            if($UseOriginal) { $ShadowHandled = $Shadow }
            if($ShadowHandled) { Write-Host $ShadowHandled }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Failed to get sudo shadow."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).