# Copy a file to a directory outside of a GitHub Action Runner directory within a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, github, github-actions

I have a self-hosted GitHub Action Runner that builds a Visual Studio solution and then launches a powershell script that lives inside the repo. This script modifies some files in the repo. I would like these modified files to also be copied to a folder outside the GitHub Action Runner directory as the last step of my action within my PC (Windows 10). This is what the launched script looks like:

```
$scriptFile = Get-Item ".\SFDScripts\Internal\Hardcore\Hardcore.cs"
$maps = Get-ChildItem ".\SFDScripts\Internal\Hardcore\Maps\"

foreach ($map in $maps) {

    if ($map.PSIsContainer) { continue }

    # This modifies the file at {$map.FullName}
    SFDScriptInjector $scriptFile.FullName $map.FullName 

    # Then I want to copy that file to a specific directory on the device where the GitHub Action Runner runs
    Copy-Item $map.FullName "C:\Users\juans\OneDrive\Documents\Superfighters Deluxe\Maps\Custom"
}
```

I am currently getting an error at the `Copy-Item $map.FullName "C:\Users\juans\OneDrive\Documents\Superfighters Deluxe\Maps\Custom"` line.  The error is the following

```
Copy-Item : Access is denied
At E:\actions-runner\_work\SFDScripts\SFDScripts\injectScriptToAllMaps.ps1:7 char:5
+     Copy-Item $map.FullName "C:\Users\juans\OneDrive\Documents\Superf ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
 
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I also tried running the script using this [`run_as.ps1` script](https://github.com/Juansero29/SFDScripts/blob/master/run_as.ps1). This allows the Action to finish without errors, but the files are still not copied (I'm guessing it fails silently inside the new instance of powershell.

[Here is the .yml action file](https://github.com/Juansero29/SFDScripts/blob/master/.github/workflows/dotnet-desktop.yml) at its current state.

I can't find out how to give access to the github runner to modify external directories. So, how can I make it to copy the file to an external directory?

Comment: Did you try using SUDO on your github action workflow with the Copy-Item line?

Comment: SUDO doesn't exist in powershell... or is there an alternative?

Comment: I found some orientations here for sudo equivalent with powershell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314557/how-to-sudo-on-powershell-on-windows

Comment: Has your Powershell script have the “execute” filesystem permission set? (could be similar to this issue as well: https://github.community/t/action-showing-permission-denied/134957)

Comment: Interesting. Does the github action run from powershell already though? I mean, when you do something like this:
`run: msbuild $env:Solution_Name /t:Restore` does it run inside powershell if this is a self-hosted runner running on windows? Or does it run in cmd, or something else?

Comment: So I modified the run to this: `Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe -Args "-executionpolicy bypass -command Set-Location \`"$PWD\`"; .\injectScriptToAllMaps.ps1"` and it is the same behavior as with `.\run_as.ps1`. 

I also run this command based on the second link you sent me : `git update-index --chmod=+x .\injectScriptToAllMaps.ps1`.

Now the action doesn't fail but the files are not modified nor copied to the destination directory... so it doesn't really help :/

Comment: The default shell for windows is pwsh (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-a-specific-shell) so you don't have to specify it in the build with something like shell: pwsh (this could be used for non-windows). I found this action that could also help if necessary: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/powershell-script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230451/discussion-between-juansero29-and-guifalourd).

Answer (score 0):

What needs to be changed is actually the concerned folder Security parameters. In this case I went to the folder at `"C:\Users\juans\OneDrive\Documents\Superfighters Deluxe\Maps\Custom"` then did the following:

1. Right Click on folder > Properties > Security Tab > Advanced > Add > `Select a principal` > Advanced... > Find Now
2. In the list under `Search Results:` search for an entity with a name like `GITHUB_ActionsRunner_[short-id]`.
3. OK > OK
4. Choose the permissions you want the Github Action Runner to have on this folder, in my case: Full Control
5. OK > OK > OK

Then I re runned the Github Action, and the script was launched without any problems