# Powershell script run as administrator prompt is coming

Tags: powershell

I am having  below line of code which is part of my build process. Below code take **SectionName** and  dotnet framework path for aspnet_regiis and encryption flag -pef to encrypt my web.config.

So when build happens i need to run the below code **"Run as administrator"** for that i used start-process with powershell and -Verb runas option. But when run this script i get a prompt in windows 10 with yes or no option.

How to avoid this.

```
$args="-pef '${SectionName}' '${configfilepath}'"


Start-process powershell -Verb runas "$(join-path ${frameworkPath} 'aspnet_regiis.exe') ${args}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not the best option, you can have a shortcut to a script that runs the powershell script. Give that shortcut administrative permission and double click it / run it though CMD or something to have it run as administrator.

EDIT:
As suggested here:

[PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)

You can add an `if` statement to ensure the `-Verb runAs works.`

Comment: Thanks for replying. The above powershell is written inside a windows service or it is trigger from it. I might not be able to right click and run as administrator there. So i need to programmically allow it.

Comment: Try to make the service run the shorcut that has the administrator permission.

Comment: @Vipin Hi, once it is as windows service, if its scheduled by scheduler, I can remember there was an option to run it as administrator user, maybe that helps?

Comment: Xxxvodnikxxx we cant change it a scheduler because, we are using this code inside a deployment script which is triggered from a told called octopus. Which is a deployment tool