# How to execute a PowerShell script on a remote server elevated as administrator

Tags: python, powershell, winrm

I need to execute some **PowerShell** stuff and this only works if I execute this when the Powershell is open with **administrator privilege**

But, I need to run this through `WinRM`

And I'm not finding a way to handle this

**Additional information:**

Powershell 5.1

The python application is not running on this Windows Server

And I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31602095/1698509) but didn't work for me / in this case

I'm using https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm

Comment: I have no idea if this will work with `PyWinRM` (I've never used that), but one thing to consider is the use of [Constrained Endpoints](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introduction-to-powershell-endpoints/).  These are typically used to limit the available commands for remote users, but, more pertinent for you, also allow the commands to automatically run with alternative credentials - so, a normal domain user could connect and execute commands as a domain admin without needing to know the credentials of the elevated account.