# Windows Server 2019 GCP CE PowerShell Startup Script - Chocolately Not Completing

Tags: powershell, google-compute-engine, chocolatey, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 GCP Compute Engine instance with the network tags `http-server` and `https-server`.

When creating this instance, I have a two-line PowerShell startup script that's meant to install [Chocolately](https://chocolatey.org/) and, through Chocolately, Python:

```
iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
choco install -y python
```

However, the startup script gets stuck on installing Python. No error is thrown, but when I connect to the VM with Microsoft Remote Desktop, Python is not installed. And if I try running these commands in a PowerShell script within the VM, it succeeds.

I would think with the ["Confirm all prompts" option `-y`](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/install#options-and-switches) that the script wouldn't hang. Why does the startup script fail to complete?

I'll post below the startup script output from [Serial port 1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/windows#viewing-output):

```
2022/01/11 19:05:24 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Forcing web requests to allow TLS v1.2 (Required for requests to Chocolatey.org)
2022/01/11 19:05:24 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Getting latest version of the Chocolatey package for download.
2022/01/11 19:05:24 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Not using proxy.
2022/01/11 19:05:25 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Getting Chocolatey from https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/0.11.3.
2022/01/11 19:05:25 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Downloading https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/0.11.3 to C:\Windows\TEMP\chocolatey\chocoInstall\chocolatey.zip
2022/01/11 19:05:25 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Not using proxy.
2022/01/11 19:05:25 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Extracting C:\Windows\TEMP\chocolatey\chocoInstall\chocolatey.zip to C:\Windows\TEMP\chocolatey\chocoInstall
2022/01/11 19:05:31 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Installing Chocolatey on the local machine
2022/01/11 19:05:33 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Creating ChocolateyInstall as an environment variable (targeting 'Machine')
2022/01/11 19:05:33 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:   Setting ChocolateyInstall to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey'
2022/01/11 19:05:33 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: WARNING: It's very likely you will need to close and reopen your shell
2022/01/11 19:05:33 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:   before you can use choco.
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Restricting write permissions to Administrators
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: We are setting up the Chocolatey package repository.
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: The packages themselves go to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib'
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:   (i.e. C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yourPackageName).
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: A shim file for the command line goes to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin'
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:   and points to an executable in 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yourPackageName'.
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Creating Chocolatey folders if they do not already exist.
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: WARNING: You can safely ignore errors related to missing log files when
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:   upgrading from a version of Chocolatey less than 0.9.9.
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:   'Batch file could not be found' is also safe to ignore.
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:   'The system cannot find the file specified' - also safe.
2022/01/11 19:05:36 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: chocolatey.nupkg file not installed in lib.
2022/01/11 19:05:37 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:  Attempting to locate it from bootstrapper.
2022/01/11 19:05:37 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: PATH environment variable does not have C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin in it. Adding...
2022/01/11 19:05:38 GCEInstanceSetup: Activating Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition (34e1ae55-27f8-4950-8877-7a03be5fb181) ...
2022/01/11 19:05:38 GCEInstanceSetup: Product activated successfully.
2022/01/11 19:05:40 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: WARNING: Not setting tab completion: Current user is SYSTEM user.
2022/01/11 19:05:41 GCEInstanceSetup: Activation successful.
2022/01/11 19:05:42 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Chocolatey (choco.exe) is now ready.
2022/01/11 19:05:42 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: You can call choco from anywhere, command line or powershell by typing choco.
2022/01/11 19:05:42 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Run choco /? for a list of functions.
2022/01/11 19:05:42 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: You may need to shut down and restart powershell and/or consoles
2022/01/11 19:05:42 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url:  first prior to using choco.
2022/01/11 19:05:42 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Ensuring Chocolatey commands are on the path
2022/01/11 19:05:42 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Ensuring chocolatey.nupkg is in the lib folder
2022/01/11 19:05:43 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Chocolatey v0.11.3
2022/01/11 19:05:44 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Installing the following packages:
2022/01/11 19:05:44 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: python
2022/01/11 19:05:44 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the environment is sane ... user `SYSTEM` may not be a member of `Administrators`.
For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31602095/549372), installing further packages in another shell may be able to work around this.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I tried the linked example and the other answers in that post, but the install still hangs. I'm going to test something like [scoop](https://scoop.sh/) as an alternative.