# I want to run Power Shell script with admin privileges

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I want to run this powershell script with admin privileges so it won't give me the error:

[Script Output with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdP1T.png)

Here is the script:

```
$processes = "PDStyleAgent", "AdobeIPCBroker", "CCXProcess", "RichVideo64", "CCLibrary", "AdobeNotificationClient", "AdobeUpdateService", "PDHanumanSvr", "PDR"

Foreach ($process in $processes){
    try {
    $f = Get-Process $process -ErrorAction Stop
    $f | kill
    Write-Output "$process killed."
        } 
    catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ProcessCommandException]{
    Write-Output "No instances of $process running."
        }   
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
```

I want to run this script so it kill the processes that are giving errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some way to run PowerShell with admin privileges:

1. Search Powershell from the Windows search icon OR click the Windows button from the keyboard --> write Powershell --> You will see the Windows PowerShell --> Right-click on Powershell then click Run as administrator.
2. Run this command of a PowerShell console: `Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs`
3. Run your script from PowerShell like this: `PowerShell -f C:\ScriptPath`

For more details, you can check [this StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/running-a-command-as-administrator-using-powershell).

Comment: The process you specified is a bit long as I needed to just right click and bam.. but the link you mentioned helped me. I tried those techniques but I was doing it wrong so, now it's working as I intended.

Comment: Happy to hear that your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking about. If you want to start a script as administrator, you need to open PowerShell window "As administrator".

BTW, the script itself can be simplified without losing functionality:

```
$processes = "PDStyleAgent", "AdobeIPCBroker", "CCXProcess", "RichVideo64", "CCLibrary", "AdobeNotificationClient", "AdobeUpdateService", "PDHanumanSvr", "PDR"

Get-Process -Name $processes -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a shortcut to your Powershell script on your desktop

2.Right-click the shortcut and click Properties

3.Click the Shortcut tab

4.Click Advanced

5.Select Run as Administrator

NOTE: add `powershell -f`  in front of the script path