# How to create a batch file to run cmd as administrator

Tags: batch-file

I need to run a batch file which needs to register a DLL. The DLL registration is failing because the Batch file is not  starting the command prompt as "administrator".

Is there any way to start the "**Command Prompt**" as  **administrator** through the batch file.

Environment: Win7/Vista

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994

Comment: See also [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC admin rights if required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights)

Comment: @EdGreaves is that link not to this question?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811372/how-to-code-a-bat-file-to-always-run-as-admin-mode/13811519

Comment: The question is ambiguous: is the question to run it as the user Administrator, or to run it with administrative rights?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I auto-elevate my batch file, so that it requests from UAC administrator rights if required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might have to use another batch file first to launch the second with admin rights.

In the first use

```
runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator yourbatchfile.bat
```

Upon further reading, you must be able to type in the password at the prompt. You cannot pipe the password as this feature was locked down for security reasons.

You may have more luck with [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Comment: I will try to implement your solution,

Comment: I tried the above command, but it asks for administaor password that I wont be knowing .

Comment: @JChan It seems that you can't automatically fill the password, this feature has been disabled, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 60):

This script does the trick! Just paste it into the top of your bat file. If you want to review the output of your script, add a "pause" command at the bottom of your batch file.

This script is now slightly edited to support command line args.

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin
::-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
::--------------------------------------

::ENTER YOUR CODE BELOW:
```

Comment: this code is working for enabling windows update service. But not working for disabling windows update service `sc stop wuauserv & sc config wuauserv start= disabled`

Comment: Note: this code will occasionally not function if run from sub-directories of a different drive. See my question on it here: https://superuser.com/questions/1192426/batch-file-only-runs-properly-from-c-drive/1192427#1192427

Comment: OMG - this worked perfectly! I'm of an age where everything was batch files and DOS programming, and know most tricks but didn't realise this was possible! I'm highly impressed! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Calling the script with args: %* is set before the code but empty after the last line

Comment: such a tremendous boilerplate for a simple action!

Answer (score 10):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and double-click a shortcut to run as an elevated process.

Works from the start menu as well.

Answer (score 7):

(This is based on [@DarkXphenomenon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11525223/835945), which unfortunately had some problems.)

You need to enclose your code within this wrapper:

```
if _%1_==_payload_  goto :payload

:getadmin
    echo %~nx0: elevating self
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)                >> "%vbs%"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof

:payload
    echo %~nx0: running payload with parameters:
    echo %*
    echo ---------------------------------------------------
    cd /d %2
    shift
    shift
    rem put your code here
    rem e.g.: perl myscript.pl %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
goto :eof
```

This makes batch file run itself as elevated user.  It adds two parameters to the privileged code:

- word `payload`, to indicate this is payload call, i.e. already elevated.  Otherwise
  it would just open new processes over and over.
- directory path where the main script was called.  Due to the fact that Windows *always*
  starts elevated cmd.exe in "%windir%\system32", there's no easy way of knowing what
  the original path was (*and* retaining ability to copy your script around without
  touching code)

**Note:** Unfortunately, for some reason `shift` does not work for `%*`, so if you need
    to pass actual arguments on, you will have to resort to the ugly notation I used
    in the example (`%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`), which also brings in the limit of
    maximum of 9 arguments

Answer (score 7):

To prevent the script from failing when the script file resides on a non system drive (c:) and in a directory with spaces.

**Batch_Script_Run_As_Admin.cmd**

```
@echo off
if _%1_==_payload_  goto :payload

:getadmin
    echo %~nx0: elevating self
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)                >> "%vbs%"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof

:payload

::ENTER YOUR CODE BELOW::   





::END OF YOUR CODE::

echo.
echo...Script Complete....
echo.

pause
```

Comment: This code seems to be working, but I always need to confirm. Is there any way to auto-confirm without user interaction? cheers!

Comment: I'm calling the batch from vba but for some reason when I add this the code thinks the execution was finish and it keep going. How Can I wait until the execution finish

Answer (score 6):

You can use a shortcut that links to the batch file. Just go into properties for the shortcut and select advanced, then "run as administrator".

Then just make the batch file hidden, and run the shortcut.

This way, you can even set your own icon for the shortcut.

Comment: My `run as administrator` checkbox is disabled. How can I get over it?

Comment: Hm, not sure. That's interesting.

Comment: @NamGVU https://superuser.com/questions/880290/run-as-administrator-greyed-out-on-shortcut

Comment: @NamGVU You can download already created portable (generated in the `Windows XP`) shortcuts set from here: https://sourceforge.net/p/contools/contools/HEAD/tree/trunk/Scripts/Tools/ToolAdaptors/lnk/ Or even generate your own: https://sourceforge.net/p/contools/contools/HEAD/tree/trunk/Scripts/Tools/ToolAdaptors/vbs/

Answer (score 5):

This Works for me in Windows 7 to 10 with parameters, when kick starting app or file from anywhere (including browser) and also when accessing file from anywhere. Replace (*YOUR BATCH SCRIPT HERE* anchor) with your code. This solution May Help :)

```
@echo off

call :isAdmin

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    goto :run
) else (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto :UACPrompt
)

exit /b

:isAdmin
    fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% >nul
exit /b

:run
  <YOUR BATCH SCRIPT HERE>
exit /b

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %~1", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
if "%~s0"=="%~s1" ( cd %~sp1 & shift ) else (
  echo CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^).ShellExecute "%~s0","%~0 %*","","runas",1 >"%tmp%%~n0.vbs" & "%tmp%%~n0.vbs" & del /q "%tmp%%~n0.vbs" & goto :eof
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As user2549366 suggested before, "You can use a shortcut that links to the batch file." but in the Properties->Compatibility tab of the shortcut, run as administrator may be disabled.

So instead You just right click on your "file.bat - shortcut" then go to ->Properties->Shortcut tab -> Advanced and there you can click Run as administrator. After that, You can execute the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the under codes to run a CMD as administrator via a batch file.

```
@echo off
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/k cd /d %~dp0'"
exit
```

This code uses PowerShell to start a new Command Prompt process with administrative privileges. The -Verb RunAs parameter tells PowerShell to run the process as an administrator, and the /k cd /d %~dp0 argument changes the directory to the location of the batch file But, I used it for windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Add one line at the beginning of the batch file to run cmd as administrator

title C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Answer (score -2):

Here's a more simple version of essentially the same file.

```
@echo off
break off
title C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
cls

:cmd
set /p cmd=C:\Enter Command:

%cmd%
echo.
goto cmd
```

Comment: This only mask a console, not asking for elevate as administrator

Answer (score -5):

Make a text using notepad or any text editor of you choice. Open notepad, write this short command "cmd.exe" without the quote aand save it as cmd.bat.

Click cmd.bat and choose "run as administrator".