# Run cmd in admin mode using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-installer, administrator

I have a msi installer that needs to be run in silent mode. For that I need to run the installer in silent mode through an elevated command prompt. How can I launch the cmd in elevated mode and then run the command to execute installer from that elevated cms using a batch file?

Comment: same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525056/how-to-create-a-batch-file-to-run-cmd-as-administrator

Comment: I need to schedule the batch file on a daily basis.So, I cannot enter the password every time. It has to be automated. Is there any other way out?

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights

Comment: nah..nothing..What if I schedule my batch file to run with highest privileges? What happens in that case?

Comment: That should probably work.

Comment: Scheduling the batch file with highest privileges does work for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a batch file and call the msi installer from it.
2. Then create a shortcut to the batch file.
3. Right click on the shortcut -> Properties -> Shortcut tab -> Advanced.
4. Click **Run as administrator**. Execute the batch script from the shortcut.
5. In the scheduler, give the path to this shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all programs (including command prompt) to run in admin mode by default, then disable UAC by making enableLUA=0 in registry. Note that this change will prompt for system restart.

EnableLUA can be found under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System.

Once the system comes up, then all programs will run in elevated (admin) mode by default.