# Copying file to Startup folder for All Users

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that will copy itself to the startup folder in Windows 7 for all users.

I have tried this code here:

```
copy test.bat "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

and it does notwork. However, if I input this code instead:

```
copy test.bat "C:\Users\Kreature\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

it works but the problem is that I need this to be universal for all accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you must call the script from an admin account in order to copy a file to the system folders. Try "Execute as administrator" on CMD and call your script.

Comment: i think your right because i tried in cmd and it said access denied also running the file as admin did nothing, 0 file copyied. idk what to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525056/how-to-create-a-batch-file-to-run-cmd-as-administrator

You could try this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you don't have permissions to write to folders shared by all users, so the first part fails. But you can write to your own folders, so that part works.

Comment: hmmm okay, umm is there a way to give permission mayby add a line of code to force admin... but i ran as admin and nothing

Comment: Could you maybe say what the error message you get is?

Comment: C:\Users\Kreature\Desktop>copy test.bat "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
Menu\Programs\Startup"
Access is denied.
        0 file(s) copied.

Comment: in cmd it just says  Access is denied. 0 file(s) copied

Comment: ok so drag and drop works with the file but asks for admin permision but yet running the bat file as admin does nothing

Comment: ok i got it figured out in a way. i compiled the .bat file to a .exe file with admin manifest using a bat to exe converter and it copyied over, would still be nice to find a way to do it without clicking yes for admin permision

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:
copy test.bat "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
%USERNAME% will be automatically filled in with the user's username.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - which clearly states that expected outcome is to copy file to startup folder for *all* users.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for a solution and couldn't find any so i dived in batch basic and realized it's pretty simple. Hoping you have the file you need copied to every user startup and you have admin privs on the system. create a batch file as below:

```
@echo off
set back=%cd%
for /d %%i in ("C:\Users\"*) do (
cd "%%i"
REM copy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\file.cmd" "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
echo.
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dir "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
cd ..
timeout 2 > NUL
)
cd %back%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
copy %0 "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

%0 stand for local file with path. U can change the %0 to any file you want.

%appdata% will redirect you to this path : `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming`

Answer (score 0):

I made this script that copies any files to startup.
I made it in Windows 10 so I don't know if it will work.

try this instead:

copy "example.bat" "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

It also works with .txt, .bat, .vbs, ... files.

If you want you can try it on older versions of Windows, it should work..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).