# How run file .bat as admin

Tags: batch-file, cmd, admin

I have question how run file .bat as admin? How run cmd as admin in file bat?

I must run command on cmd:
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -px "MyKey" c:\key.xml -pri

Please help and have any tips or any good material.

Comment: `bash` != `batch`. Bash is a command shell for Linux operating systems, and `batch-file` and `cmd` (and `%windir%` and `Microsoft.NET`) are Windows (which is *not* Linux). Please take care to read the description of tags before using them, and make sure you choose tags that actually are relevant to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run BAT as admin (w/o shortcut)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117227/run-bat-as-admin-w-o-shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

Use `RUNAS` command for this purpose like below. See help using `runas /?` in command prompt

```
runas /user:administrator "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.5
0727\aspnet_regiis.exe -px "MyKey" d:\key.xml -pri"

Enter the password for administrator:
```

Answer (score 0):

open start menu by pressing windows key type `cmd` right click `cmd` and select `Run as administrator` this will open the command prompt in administrator mode and then you can run your command as an administrator.

Comment: It must be a script file, this way I know

Comment: Run the script from the administrator’s command prompt itself. for example : if your script is located at `c:\folder\script.bat` go to  that directory `cd c:\folder`  and run `script.bat`