# How can i run code in an elevated cmd using bat?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, elevated-privileges

im trying to get a stubborn game to close whenever it freezes. i need an elevated cmd to do so and ive managed to open one using bat;

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process 'cmd.exe' -Verb runAs"
```

i then need to run

```
taskkill /f /pid game.exe
```

inside of this elevated cmd. any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the help/usage for the `Start-Process` cmdlet? _`-ArgumentList`_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run BAT as admin (w/o shortcut)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117227/run-bat-as-admin-w-o-shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a command inside the elevated cmd, add -ArgumentList:
"/c" tells cmd.exe to run the given command

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process 'cmd.exe' -ArgumentList @('/c taskkill /f /pid game.exe') -Verb runAs"
```