# How to detect if a batch script is running with administrative rights?

Tags: windows, batch-file

At first: Yes, I know different answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights#8995407), but this is not what I want ...

I have a Batch script (on Win7) which must be executed with Administrator rights. To do that the user must right click the Batch file and select "Runs as administrator" to execute the script. The "NET SESSION", "AT" and so on solutions of answers like in the link above doesn't not work, because "NET SESSION" returns me the same result: there is no different if I start the Batch file with a double click or if I start it while selecting "Run as Administrator". But I need to find out if the Batch file is started with "Run as administrator" ...

Any Solutions for that?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811372/how-to-code-a-bat-file-to-always-run-as-admin-mode)

Comment: @Kao: Thanks, but the user is already a adminsitrator. I must "only" check if the Batch is realy started with "Run as Administrator" like it was described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13811519/1465758

Comment: @Steffen is a shortcut to the batch (with "run as administrator" thick) an option?

Comment: @npocmaka: The question is: How can I (inside the Batch program) find out if the the Batch was started with "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: @Steffen - the link you provided answers this in fact

Comment: Yes, that right. See also at my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Thanks for your comments. Today I figure out what happens.

Our admin has change the configuration of the cmd.exe application so that the cmd.exe starts in every case with administration rights. So theres no different between a double click on "cmd.exe" and starting it with "Run as Adminstrator". And so my script returns the same result in both cases!