# c# winforms Application, run a cmd command as system

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, runas

I have written a program in the last days which automatically changes the proxy server. This runs as a Windows Forms Tray Application on the user level.
Now came a request which caused me some problems. A cmd command "ipconfig /registerdns" should be executed but this requires higher permissions.
I'm now looking for a way to easily execute this command in normal user context. Is there a way to run this one command as a system? Or any other possibility?

Or is there another function to re-register the dns without admin priviledge?

I hope there is a easy way.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found no solution for my former problem, because it is not possible to launch a elevated command from a user Application. But I found a powershell command: Register-DnsClient. This command does the same and does not need elevated priviledges. Only downside is it works only on Windows 8.1 and newer. So Windows 7 is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

As i know admin processes can only be created by another admin processes but still you can try adding this parameter to your process's start info

```
StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

if it doesnt work you set your application to run always as admin by adding app.manifest to your project and editing line 19 as below.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a script (.cmd or .bat) containing required command (here: "ipconfig /registerdns"), then flag it as "Run as administrator". Finally, run this script from your app instead of original command.
This should help in flagging as "Run as administrator": [How to code a BAT file to always run as admin mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811372/how-to-code-a-bat-file-to-always-run-as-admin-mode)