# Can I run Regini "as admin" from within a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, permissions, registry

I have a batch file for Win 10:  run.bat

Within the batch file, I want to run Regini (app to modify registry permissions).

> regini run.bat

I tested this line using CMD prompt. Regular prompt does not work. But if I run CMD prompt "as admin", it works.

*Run.bat* contains
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies [9]

**QUESTION: Is there a way to run "regini" as admin from within a batch file?**

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Plan is to run batch file in Win 10 Enterprise 2021 LTSC.

Answer (score 0):

from what you explain, this could be the solution you're looking for. If the batch runs "as admin", all executed commands within will do as well.

```
set "params=%*" 
cd /d "%~dp0" && ( if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ) && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>nul 2>nul || (  echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~sdp0"" && %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && exit /B )
```

the original post and more explanation can be found here
[How to code a BAT file to always run as admin mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811372/how-to-code-a-bat-file-to-always-run-as-admin-mode)