# Is it possible to make a shortcut to a relative path in Windows that runs as admin?

Tags: windows, relative-path, uac, shortcut

To create a shortcut with a relative path, set the target to the following.

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start your_relpath\app.exe [your_args]
```

It is also straightforward to make the program run as administrator.

```
Properties > Advanced > Run as administrator
```

But putting the two together doesn't work. When `cmd.exe` is started as admin, it loses the current working directory and goes to `%windir%\system32`. The relative path starts there which is not intended.

Is there any way to make a shortcut that is **both** relative and run as admin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't find an easy way but that's fine. I was concerned that shortcuts with absolute paths would break between computers. I didn't realize that Windows corrected them automatically. This seems sufficient, though relative paths would have been more elegant.

> Although shortcuts, when created, point to specific files or folders, they may break if the target is moved to another location. Microsoft Windows has standard algorithms for fixing up shortcuts when they are moved. Windows 9x-based versions of Windows use a simple search algorithm to fix broken shortcuts.[1] On Windows NT-based operating systems and the NTFS file system, the target object's unique identifier is stored in the shortcut file and Windows can use the Distributed Link Tracking service for tracking the targets of shortcuts, so that the shortcut may be silently updated if the target moves to another hard drive.[4]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_shortcut#Microsoft_Windows

Answer (score 3):

For a portable shortcut, that works with a relative path, use the following:

Simply drop this in the "Target" of the Shortcut Properties:

```
%COMSPEC% /C "start GoogleChromePortable.exe -enableextensions -incognito"
```

Expected behavior:
A brief CMD window will popup and close just prior to chrome launching.

Note: the "Start in:" option can be left blank. 
Also note, the .exe is located in the same folder as the shortcut, but move the folder and the shortcut works just fine.

This is confirmed to work in Win10 1607.

Credit: some other post on stackoverflow a while ago.

Comment: I tried this with Target and Start In blank, with a .bat file, but it is not working. I'm looking for a way to run a .bat as admin on a portable key using shortcuts.  %COMSPEC% /C "cmd _UTT.bat" worked though, but won't run as admin.

Answer (score 2):

Was having trouble with auto-close window behavior. Just got it working with the following:

`%COMSPEC% /c "start theRelativePath" | taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and solved it using four files: two .bat files and a shortcut to each.

I wanted a shortcut that a customer could double-click on to update a kiosk from a USB drive/stick.

The first bat file, not running in administrative mode, is launched by a shortcut. That bat file sets an environment variable with the current directory that all four of the files are in (on the USB drive). It then kicks off the second bat file via a shortcut.

The second bat file runs in administrative mode (in the shortcut properties, use the “Advanced..” button to set this) and uses the environment variable set by the first bat file. This second bat file uses robocopy to copy the updated file(s) to the kiosk application folder.

File: **Update_the_Kiosk_01.bat**:

```
Setx MYSAVEDDIR %CD% 
start "Kiosk Update" /d %MYSAVEDDIR% %MYSAVEDDIR%\Update_the_Kiosk_02.bat-Shortcut.lnk
```

File: **Update_the_Kiosk_02.bat**:

```
robocopy %MYSAVEDDIR%\bin\ C:\KIOSK_APP_DIR\bin\   "myFile_newVersion" /copyall /v /MT
```

The first shortcut, named “**Run_Me_To_Update_Kiosk**” has a target of:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k Update_the_Kiosk_01.bat
```

The second shortcut, named “**Update_the_Kiosk_02.bat-Shortcut**” has a target of:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k cd /D %MYSAVEDDIR% & Update_the_Kiosk_02.bat
```

Note that in the first bat file, I needed to specify the link extension “.lnk” even though I can’t see that extension in the filename in a File Explorer window.

Double-click on **Run_Me_To_Update_Kiosk** to kick it off.

I am sure there is room for improvement, but this worked for me on Windows 10 and Windows 11.