# Using the %~dp0 special character in a Windows shortcut

Tags: windows

I am trying to create a shortcut in windows which points to an .exe file in the same folder. The catch is that I would like the shortcut to work even when the .exe and shortcut are moved to different folder together. Therefore the shortcut should point to a relative path, not an absolute path

My first idea was to create a .bat file which (1) first navigates to its own location using the special character %~dp0, then (2) runs the exe.

```
cd %~dp0
MyFile.exe
```

However, this is not working because command line is disabled on the network I am working on.

My second idea was to follow the instructions here: [Is it possible to make a shortcut to a relative path in Windows that runs as admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756671/is-it-possible-to-make-a-shortcut-to-a-relative-path-in-windows-that-runs-as-adm) and set the shortcut's target to `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe` or `%COMSPEC%`, both are kinda of faux ways of making a shortcut run the command line.

Still no luck, my network administrator has disabled this functionality as well.

That being said, is there a way to use the special character `%~dp0` directly in the "target" field of a windows shortcut? I would ideally like to just set the target of the shortcut to

```
%~dp0/MyFile.exe
```

But maybe there is some syntax I am missing here.

Comment: `%~` is CMD syntax for batch file parameters and loop variables. This syntax has no meaning in a shell shortcut.

Comment: Explorer should store a [relative target path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871306.aspx) in the .LNK shortcut. It just doesn't display this relative path in the interface. The relative path gets used when resolving the shortcut, which actually rewrites the .LNK file at the time the path is resolved. But it only resolves the relative path to update the shortcut if the original target no longer exists.