# Windows batch file starting directory when run from 'shortcut' and 'run as admin'

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, uac

My case is similar to the question (except what to mention after): 
**[Windows batch file starting directory when 'run as admin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672693/windows-batch-file-starting-directory-when-run-as-admin)**

Brief:

> I have a batch file which is in a directory and must be run from there as well because it updates files within this directory.
>
> Is there any way to still be able to know from which directory the batch file was run ***(when it's run as administrator)***?
> I don't want the user to enter the directory manually.

The solution mentioned that I used is:

> Try to access the batch files path like this:
>
> ```
> echo %~dp0
> ```

**Now my case is as follow:**
I have shortcuts for my batch file in other directories. When I run one of the shortcuts, the starting directory is that of the original batch file (not the path of the shortcut).

Is there any way to still be able to know from which directory the **shortcut** (of the batch file) was run?

Comment: Did you mean that your are looking for folder target ?

Comment: I'm looking for getting the directory in which the shortcut (from which I executed the batch file) is currently in.

Comment: I had forgotten how broken the run as administrator shortcuts were.  Got an idea I need to test ...

Answer (score 1):

Copy this script into each directory that has one of your shortcuts. Modify the shortcuts to call this script. Then modify your script to use %CD%.

```
@cd /d %~dp0
@call path\to\your\script.cmd
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It gets the directory `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: Answer updated.  Apologies for the late response and failing to cover the admin angle in the original.